# Should I use the datetime or timestamp data type in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, datetime, timestamp, sqldatatypes

Would you recommend using a [datetime](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html) or a [timestamp](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html) field, and why (using MySQL)?

I'm working with PHP on the server side.

Comment: this has some relevant information https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1215635/MySQL-DATETIME-vs-TIMESTAMP

Comment: If you want your application to be broken in February, 2038 use timestamp.  Check the date range.

Comment: If there is even the slightest chance your database might need to store values in a different Time Zone or receive connections from an application in a different Time Zone, consider using ISO-8601 CHARs for all your important timestamps. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40670532/what-are-jdbc-mysql-driver-settings-for-sane-handling-of-datetime-and-timestamp

Comment: datetime is **completely useless**. it's just a dumb string. timestamp is perfect in every way **but** it ends in 2038.

Answer (score 2122, accepted):

Timestamps in MySQL are generally used to track changes to records, and are often updated every time the record is changed. If you want to store a specific value you should use a datetime field.

If you meant that you want to decide between using a UNIX timestamp or a native MySQL datetime field, go with the native `DATETIME` format. You can do calculations within MySQL that way
`("SELECT DATE_ADD(my_datetime, INTERVAL 1 DAY)")` and it is simple to change the format of the value to a UNIX timestamp `("SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(my_datetime)")` when you query the record if you want to operate on it with PHP.

Also, as of MySQL 8.0.19 the `DATETIME` [supports time zone offsets](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html), so there's even less reason to use `TIMESTAMP` now.

Comment: An important difference is that `DATETIME` represents a date (as found in a calendar) and a time (as can be observed on a wall clock), while `TIMESTAMP` represents a well defined point in time. This could be very important if your application handles time zones. How long ago was '2010-09-01 16:31:00'? It depends on what timezone you're in. For me it was just a few seconds ago, for you it may represent a time in the future. If I say 1283351460 seconds since '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC', you know exactly what point in time I talk about. (See Nir's excellent answer below). [Downside: valid range].

Comment: Another one difference: queries with "native" datetime will not be cached, but queries with timestamp - will be.

Comment: "Timestamps in MySQL generally used to track changes to records" Do not think that's a good answer. Timestamp are a lot more powerful and complicated than that as MattBianco and Nir sayd. Although, the second part of the answer is very good. It's true what blivet said, and is a good advise.

Comment: TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC. It is the year 2022 now, 2038 is a near future. What will happen then?

Comment: This answer is completely wrong in every way.

Comment: @Fattie Can you be a little more specific? Or perhaps provide your own answer?

Comment: Or, let's avoid all the risks of using `DATETIME`/`TIMESTAMP` (timezones issues mainly) by explicitly just using a BIGINT as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/24173981/5389127

Answer (score 1055):

In MySQL 5 and above, **TIMESTAMP** values are converted from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and converted back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval. (This occurs only for the TIMESTAMP data type, and *not* for other types such as DATETIME.)

By default, the current time zone for each connection is the server's time. The time zone can be set on a per-connection basis, as described in *[MySQL Server Time Zone Support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//time-zone-support.html)*.

Comment: this OReilly presentation is very good for this topic (PDF sorry) http://cdn.oreillystatic.com/en/assets/1/event/36/Time%20Zones%20and%20MySQL%20Presentation.pdf

Comment: Its also about the nature of the event:

- A video-conference (TIMESTAMP). All attendants should see a reference to an absolute instant of time adjusted to its timezone.

- A local task time (DATETIME), i should do this task at 2014/03/31 9:00AM no matters if that day i'm working in New York or Paris. I will start to work at 8:00AM of local time of place i'll be that day.

Comment: Yes, and this is just horrible. The DBMS should never, ever convert timestamps in any direction nor taking the current DB's system time into account. It should just save the internal timestamp as it is (ms since epoch). When rendering the value (in the very last moment) the value should be presented (!) in the user's timezone from the application. Everything else is just pure pain. 

If any, the DBMS should support explicit types for local and absolute time where 'local' is something like your birthday or 'noon' and 'absolute' is something like the start time of a rocket.

Answer (score 611):

I always use DATETIME fields for anything other than row metadata (date created or modified).

As [mentioned](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html) in the MySQL documentation:

> The DATETIME type is used when you need values that contain both date and time information. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.
>
> ...
>
> The TIMESTAMP data type has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-09 03:14:07' UTC. It has varying properties, depending on the MySQL version and the SQL mode the server is running in.

You're quite likely to hit the lower limit on TIMESTAMPs in general use -- e.g. storing birthdate.

Comment: you can also hit the *upper* limit easily if you are in banking or real estate... 30-year mortgages go beyond 2038 now

Comment: Of course, use 64-bit Unix timestamps. For example, in Java, `new Date().getTime()` already gives you a 64-bit value.

Comment: No idea. It's a much larger problem than just MySQL and there's no simple fix: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem I don't believe MySQL can just declare timestamps are now 64-bit and assume everything will be fine. They don't control the hardware.

Comment: So `timestamp` is stored internally (presumably) as a Unix timestamp - an integer. It's quick to insert and retrieve, but propably slower when applying date fucntions to it, as it will need converting to an internal datetime format to do this. So use `timestamp` for simple logging, where it will be fast, but less flexible and with a smaller range.

Answer (score 378):

The below examples show how the `TIMESTAMP` date type changed the values after changing the `time-zone to 'america/new_york'` where `DATETIME`is unchanged.

```
mysql> show variables like '%time_zone%';
+------------------+---------------------+
| Variable_name    | Value               |
+------------------+---------------------+
| system_time_zone | India Standard Time |
| time_zone        | Asia/Calcutta       |
+------------------+---------------------+

mysql> create table datedemo(
    -> mydatetime datetime,
    -> mytimestamp timestamp
    -> );

mysql> insert into datedemo values ((now()),(now()));

mysql> select * from datedemo;
+---------------------+---------------------+
| mydatetime          | mytimestamp         |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2011-08-21 14:11:09 | 2011-08-21 14:11:09 |
+---------------------+---------------------+

mysql> set time_zone="america/new_york";

mysql> select * from datedemo;
+---------------------+---------------------+
| mydatetime          | mytimestamp         |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2011-08-21 14:11:09 | 2011-08-21 04:41:09 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

I've converted my answer into article so more people can find this useful, *[MySQL: Datetime Versus Timestamp Data Types](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/22599/mysql-datetime-vs-timestamp-data-type/)*.

Comment: Well, actually the `DATETIME` effective time changed with the time-zone change, `TIMESTAMP` didn't change but the human representation did.

Answer (score 225):

The main difference is that DATETIME is constant while TIMESTAMP is affected by the `time_zone` setting.

So it only matters when you have — or may in the future have — synchronized clusters across time zones.

In simpler words: **If I have a database in Australia, and take a dump of that database to synchronize/populate a database in America, then the TIMESTAMP would update to reflect the real time of the event in the new time zone, while DATETIME would still reflect the time of the event in the au time zone**.

A great example of DATETIME being used where TIMESTAMP should have been used is in Facebook, where their servers are never quite sure what time stuff happened across time zones. Once I was having a conversation in which the time said I was replying to messages before the message was actually sent. (This, of course, could also have been caused by bad time zone translation in the messaging software if the times were being posted rather than synchronized.)

Comment: I don't think this is a good way of thinking. I'd just store and process all the dates in UTC and make sure that the front-end displays it according to the given time-zone. This approach is simple and predictable.

Comment: @Kos: isn't storing and processing all dates in UTC exactly what TIMESTAMP is doing internally? (Then converting it to display your local timezone?)

Comment: _my_ local timezone? How would your DB know my timezone? ;-) There's normally quite some processing between the database and the user interface. I do the localisation only after the whole processing.

Comment: @Koz: my database doesnt know your databases timezone :! But it does know the timestamp. Your database knows its own timezone setting and applies that when interpreting/representing the timestamp. 1:01am on Dec 11 2013 in Beijing China is not the same moment in time as 1:01am on Dec 11 2013 in Sydney Australia. Google: 'time zones' and 'prime meridian'.

Comment: yes, TIMESTAMP effectively stores (a limited range) times in UTC.  but then effectively hides it from you.   highly recommend only using datetime and only storing UTC, and avoiding all functions that use the connection timezone (now, current_date, unix_timestamp, etc).

Answer (score 147):

I make this decision on a semantic base.

I use a timestamp when I need to record a (more or less) fixed point in time. For example when a record was inserted into the database or when some user action took place.

I use a datetime field when the date/time can be set and changed arbitrarily. For example when a user can save later change appointments.

Comment: timestamp- fixed point in time, Coordinated Universal Time

datetime - relative to a point of view, to a time reference (ej timezone local time), could be.. Coordinated Local Time?

Comment: Make sense. If user sent SMS and one admin in US needs to know when and another admin in Europe needs to know when. They will get time for their timezone and wont even blink. If I as user in plane set in app at which hour should taxi come for me in UK, dear god if some timezones jump into that.

Answer (score 143):

1. `TIMESTAMP` is four bytes vs eight bytes for `DATETIME`.
2. Timestamps are also lighter on the database and indexed faster.
3. The `DATETIME` type is used when you need values that contain both date and time information. MySQL retrieves and displays `DATETIME` values in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format. The supported range is `1000-01-01 00:00:00` to `9999-12-31 23:59:59`. The `TIMESTAMP` data type has a range of `1970-01-01 00:00:01 UTC` to `2038-01-09 03:14:07 UTC`. It has varying properties, depending on the MySQL version and the SQL mode the server is running in.
4. `DATETIME` is constant while `TIMESTAMP` is affected by the `time_zone` setting.

Comment: You need to clarify #4: Timestamp as stored is constant and non-relative (completely agnostic) to timezone, while the displayed output on retrieval is affected by the timezone of the requesting session. DATETIME is always relative to the timezone it was recorded in, and must always be considered in that context, a responsibility that now falls to the application.

Answer (score 139):

I recommend using **neither** a DATETIME or a TIMESTAMP field.  If you want to represent a specific day as a whole (like a birthday), then use a DATE type, but if you're being more specific than that, you're probably interested in recording an actual moment as opposed to a unit of time (day,week,month,year).  Instead of using a DATETIME or TIMESTAMP, use a BIGINT, and simply store the number of milliseconds since the epoch (System.currentTimeMillis() if you're using Java).  This has several advantages:

1. You avoid vendor lock-in.  Pretty much every database supports integers in the relatively similar fashion.  Suppose you want to move to another database.  Do you want to worry about the differences between MySQL's DATETIME values and how Oracle defines them?  Even among different versions of MySQL, TIMESTAMPS have a different level of precision.  It was only just recently that MySQL supported milliseconds in the timestamps.
2. No timezone issues.  There's been some insightful comments on here on what happens with timezones with the different data types.  But is this common knowledge, and will your co-workers all take the time to learn it?  On the other hand, it's pretty hard to mess up changing a BigINT into a java.util.Date.  Using a BIGINT causes a lot of issues with timezones to fall by the wayside.
3. No worries about ranges or precision.  You don't have to worry about what being cut short by future date ranges (TIMESTAMP only goes to 2038).
4. Third-party tool integration.  By using an integer, it's trivial for 3rd party tools (e.g. EclipseLink) to interface with the database.  Not every third-party tool is going to have the same understanding of a "datetime" as MySQL does.  Want to try and figure out in Hibernate whether you should use a java.sql.TimeStamp or java.util.Date object if you're using these custom data types?  Using your base data types make's use with 3rd-party tools trivial.

This issue is closely related how you should store a money value (i.e. $1.99) in a database.  Should you use a Decimal, or the database's Money type, or worst of all a Double? All 3 of these options are terrible, for many of the same reasons listed above.  The solution is to store the value of money in cents using BIGINT, and then convert cents to dollars when you display the value to the user.  The database's job is to store data, and NOT to intrepret that data.  All these fancy data-types you see in databases(especially Oracle) add little, and start you down the road to vendor lock-in.

Comment: I like this solution. TIMESTAMP expiring in 2038 is a major problem. That's not really so far away!

Comment: It makes it hard to query data by date if its stored as a number of milliseconds

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I despise any one of the "native" date formats. Endless time zone catches etc.

Comment: @Merc no, it shouldn't be. Semantics in data structures _are_ a thing _for a reason_. Database engines have semantic types also _for a reason_. If you don't care about semantics at all, why do you use a RDBMS (relational -> based on semantic relations between data) in the first place?

Comment: @lukasz032 yes it should be. Semantics are a good thing, but when you add to the mix timezones, limitations (2038 anyone?), Messy implementation and ambiguity, then no -- real world projects will use a bigint thank you very much

Answer (score 111):

TIMESTAMP is 4 bytes Vs 8 bytes for DATETIME.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html

But like scronide said it does have a lower limit of the year 1970. It's great for anything that might happen in the future though ;)

Comment: The future ends at 2038-01-19 03:14:07 UTC.

Comment: For MySQL 8.0.28 and later running on 64-bit platforms, the valid range of argument values for UNIX_TIMESTAMP() is '1970-01-01 00:00:01.000000' UTC to '3001-01-19 03:14:07.999999' UTC (corresponding to 32536771199.999999 seconds).

Answer (score 68):

Neither. The [`DATETIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) and [`TIMESTAMP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) types are fundamentally broken for generic use cases. MySQL will change them in the future. You should use [`BIGINT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html) and UNIX timestamps unless you have a specific reason to use something else.

## Special cases

Here are some specific situations where your choice is easier and you don't need the analysis and general recommendation in this answer.

- **Date only** — if you only care about the date (like the date of the next Lunar New Year, 2022-02-01) AND you have a clear understanding of what timezone that date applies (or don't care, as in the case of Lunar New Year) then use the [`DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) column type.
- **Record insert times** — if you are logging the insert dates/times for rows in your database AND you don't care that your application [will break in the next 17 years](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html), then go ahead and use `TIMESTAMP` with a default value of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`.

## Why is `TIMESTAMP` broken?

The `TIMESTAMP` type is stored on disk in UTC timezone. This means that if you physically move your server, it does not break. That's good ✅. But timestamps as currently defined will stop working entirely in the year 2038 ❌.

Every time you `INSERT INTO` or `SELECT FROM` a `TIMESTAMP` column, the physical location (i.e. timezone configuration) of your client/application server is taken into account. If you move your application server then your dates break ❌.

*(Update 2022-04-29 MySQL [fixed this in 8.0.28](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=12654) but if your production environment is on CentOS 7 or many other flavors your migration path will be a long time until you get this support.)*

## Why is `VARCHAR` broken?

The `VARCHAR` type allows to unambiguously store a non-local date/time/both in ISO 8601 format and it works for dates past 2037. It is common to use Zulu time, but ISO 8601 allows to encode any offset. This is less useful because while MySQL date and time functions do support string as input anywhere date/time/both are expected, the result is incorrect if the input uses timezone offsets.

Also `VARCHAR` uses extra bytes of storage.

## Why is `DATETIME` broken?

A `DATETIME` stores a `DATE` and a `TIME` in the same column. Neither of these things have any meaning unless the timezone is understood, and the timezone is not stored anywhere ❌. You should put the intended timezone as a comment in the column because the timezone is inextricably linked to the data. So few people use column comments, therefore this is mistake waiting to happen. I inherited a server from Arizona, so I always need to convert all timestamps FROM Arizona time and then TO another time.

*(Update 2021-12-08 I restarted the server after years of uptime and the database client (with upgrades) reset to UTC. That means my application needs to handle dates before and after the reset differently. Hardcode!)*

The only situation a `DATETIME` is correct is to complete this sentence:

> Your year 2020 solar new year starts at exactly `DATETIME("2020-01-01 00:00:00")`.

There is no other good use for `DATETIME`s. Perhaps you will imagine a web server for a city government in Delaware. Surely the timezone for this server and all the people accessing this server can be implied to be in Delaware, with Eastern Time Zone, right? Wrong! In this millennium, we all think of servers as existing in "the cloud". So it is always wrong to think of your server in any specific timezone, because your server will be moved some day.

Note: MySQL now [supports time zone offsets](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-19.html) in `DATETIME` literals ([thanks @Marko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/should-i-use-the-datetime-or-timestamp-data-type-in-mysql/59460086?noredirect=1#comment112665253_59460086)). This may make inserting `DATETIME`s more convenient for you but does not address the incomplete and therefore useless meaning of the data, this fatal issue identifies ("❌") above.

## How to use `BIGINT`?

**Define:**

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE good_times (
    a_time BIGINT
)
```

**Insert a specific value:**

```sql
INSERT INTO good_times VALUES (
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONVERT_TZ("2014-12-03 12:24:54", '+00:00', @@global.time_zone))
);
```

**Insert a default value (thx [Brad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/should-i-use-the-datetime-or-timestamp-data-type-in-mysql/59460086?noredirect=1#comment131004105_59460086)):**

```sql
ALTER TABLE good_times MODIFY a_time BIGINT DEFAULT (UNIX_TIMESTAMP());
```

Or of course this is much better from your application, like:

```php
$statement = $myDB->prepare('INSERT INTO good_times VALUES (?)');
$statement->execute([$someTime->getTimestamp()]);
```

**Select:**

```sql
SELECT a_time FROM good_times;
```

There are techniques for filtering relative times (select posts within the past 30 days, find users that bought within 10 minutes of registering) beyond the scope here.

Comment: Your point that DATETIME doesn't have meaning unless the timezone is understood doesn't make it broken. Your application code should convert the datetime value to the desired timezone before it inserts it into the database, so upon retrieval of the value from the database you will know what timezone it's in. Even that is unnecessary if your app doesn't care about the timezone, which would be the case when all of app's users are within the same timezone (e.g. app is used only in France).

Comment: @Marko that argument applies equally well to storing datetime values into a database as a `VARCHAR`: your application code should convert the value to the desired format before it inserts into the database. My opinion is that databases are made to store data including all context necessary for that data to have meaning.

Comment: no it doesn’t apply equally well because you cannot manipulate VARCHAR values using database built-in date functions and date comparison operators

Comment: Here is a MySQL built-in function applying to an ISO 8601 `VARCHAR` value: `SELECT DATE_ADD("2020-01-01", INTERVAL 2 DAY)`. Here is a MySQL built-in date comparison operator applying ISO 8601 `VARCHAR`s: `SELECT "2020-01-01" < "2020-03-01"`

Comment: It works with ISO 8601 string because MySQL recongizes it as a date literal and implicitly casts the VARCHAR value to DATE. The difference is that storing the value in a VARCHAR column will take 10 bytes, whereas storing it in a DATE column will take 3 bytes. I also reckon that the VARCHAR value will be implicitly casted EVERY TIME you use it with built-in date function or date comparison operators, which is far from efficient. DATE and DATETIME types are implemented for a reason. Also, as of MySQL 8.0.19 t's possible to specify timezone offset with DATETIME.

Comment: to correct myself, ISO 8601 VARCHAR string will take up 11 bytes of data, not 10.

Comment: ① You have conceded that using `DATETIME` and `VARCHAR` are equally effective. ② You raise a new point that `VARCHAR` uses more storage than `DATE`, which of course I agree. It is now a matter of preference whether a data designer prefers a wasteful approach (`VARCHAR`) or an unsafe one (`DATETIME`). ③ Lastly you mention about version 8.0.19. Thank you, this is relevant information that I have added to the answer, with credit.

Comment: By your logic, we could store numbers as VARCHAR as well, it works perfectly fine in MySQL but it's still a bad design. They may be equally effective but are not equally efficient, in terms of storage AND execution speed.  DATETIME was made for a reason, don't know why you're trying to dispute that.

Comment: We can store anything as anything. But only `BIGINT` logically represents a non-local time. `DATETIME` was designed to support the 1960s definition of SQL (doi:10.1145/362384.362685). At that time nobody thought about timezones and MySQL has made scant improvements on the topic since.

Comment: I don't see how your last comment is relevant. Your original point was that DATETIME is unnecessary because we could simply store data as VARCHAR. Like I said, by that logic we could also store numbers as VARCHAR, but we do not do that because having a dedicated data type with operations optimized for it makes the execution much faster and uses less storage.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer, with very detailed arguments on why it was provided; most of these comments are ridiculous: TIMESTAMP and DATETIME are both ridiculous, and shouldn't be used.

Comment: I still don't understand the point of this. If you store any date in UTC, and run all your servers in UTC, you have a clear understanding of your data. Thus, you can serve dates to clients as `2022-01-23T09:59:56+00:00`, and they can apply formatting according to the users' timezone. What am I missing here?

Comment: Because some database administrator don't have full control over which server their application runs on. Maybe your database is sent back to QA/DEV and they have a different timezone, things break. I had a server in UTC-8 timezone, everything was fine. But when it restarted it was suddenly UTC. I have root access there and this change was unexpected. Using `BIGINT` never breaks ever.

Comment: Heres stidbit for you, auto genreated timestamp for bigint. I was struggling with this and found mysql 8 lets you use `unix_timestamp()` as a default if you add extra `()` around it. Would really complete the answer if you add this I think.

Comment: Trying to understand what's wrong wrong with @MoritzFriedrich's comment, as they say if you store everything in UTC, that wouldn't mean you're relying on the server location but on using sthg like `autodtime datetime(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT UTC_TIMESTAMP` and `INSERT INTO timetest (dtime) VALUES (UTC_TIMESTAMP)`, why would this ever break @WilliamEntriken? The misconception might have happened that I think @MoritzFriedrich was talking about UTC-0 and not some arbitrary offsetted UTC, please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @CanRau if you store a UTC+0 time in a `DATETIME` field your application will work.  However you should document such everywhere that column is used (possibly naming with `_UTC`) because you are adding more meaning on top of what MySQL specifies.

Comment: Thanks for getting back, okay I see your point and consider adding documentation, probably also column comments. To me personally it feels clearer to always store UTC+0

Answer (score 55):

Depends on application, really.

Consider setting a timestamp by a user to a server in New York, for an appointment in Sanghai. Now when the user connects in Sanghai, he accesses the same appointment timestamp from a mirrored server in Tokyo. He will see the appointment in Tokyo time, offset from the original New York time.

So for values that represent user time like an appointment or a schedule, datetime is better. It allows the user to control the exact date and time desired, regardless of the server settings. The set time is the set time, not affected by the server's time zone, the user's time zone, or by changes in the way daylight savings time is calculated (yes it does change).

On the other hand, for values that represent system time like payment transactions, table modifications or logging, always use timestamps. The system will not be affected by moving the server to another time zone, or when comparing between servers in different timezones.

Timestamps are also lighter on the database and indexed faster.

Comment: Your application should not rely on the timezone of the server. An application should ALWAYS select the timezone in the session of the database connection it uses before issuing any query. If a connection is shared between multiple users (ex: webapp), use UTC and do timezone conversion on the rendering side.

Answer (score 52):

### *2016 +*: what I advise is to set your Mysql timezone to UTC and use DATETIME:

Any recent front-end framework (Angular 1/2, react, Vue,...) can easily and automatically convert your UTC datetime to local time.

Additionally:

- DATETIME can now be **automatically** set to the current time value [How do you set a default value for a MySQL Datetime column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168736/how-do-you-set-a-default-value-for-a-mysql-datetime-column/10603198#10603198)
- Contrary to what one might think, DATETIME is **FASTER** THAN TIMESTAMP,
  http://gpshumano.blogs.dri.pt/2009/07/06/mysql-datetime-vs-timestamp-vs-int-performance-and-benchmarking-with-myisam/
- TIMESTAMP is still limited to 1970-2038

(Unless you are likely to change the timezone of your servers)

---

Example with AngularJs

```
// back-end: format for angular within the sql query
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(my_datetime, "%Y-%m-%dT%TZ")...

// font-end Output the localised time
{{item.my_datetime | date :'medium' }}
```

All localised time format available here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: Your data should not be attached to the time zone settings of your servers. Maybe, it's working for your if you have single MySql box under your desk

Answer (score 43):

TIMESTAMP is always in UTC (that is, elapsed seconds since 1970-01-01, in UTC), and your MySQL server auto-converts it to the date/time for the connection timezone. In the long-term, TIMESTAMP is the way to go because you know your temporal data will always be in UTC. For example, you won't screw your dates up if you migrate to a different server or if you change the timezone settings on your server.

Note: default connection timezone is the server timezone, but this can (should) be changed per session (see `SET time_zone = ...`).

Answer (score 42):

A `timestamp` field is a special case of the `datetime` field. You can create `timestamp` columns to have special properties; it can be set to update itself on either create and/or update.

In "bigger" database terms, `timestamp` has a couple of special-case triggers on it.

What the right one is depends entirely on what you want to do.

Comment: No, the difference is not just "a special case". Because timezones of the session that sets/queries the values are involved differently.

Answer (score 36):

Comparison between DATETIME, TIMESTAMP and DATE

[image]

**What is that [.fraction]?**

- A DATETIME or TIMESTAMP value can include a trailing fractional
  seconds part in up to microseconds (6 digits) precision. In
  particular, any fractional part in a value inserted into a DATETIME
  or TIMESTAMP column is stored rather than discarded. This is of course optional.

Sources:

- [MySQL Date/Time data types reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html)
- [MySQL Storage Requirements reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html)

Answer (score 29):

It is worth noting in MySQL you can use something along the lines of the below when creating your table columns:

```
on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

This will update the time at each instance you modify a row and is sometimes very helpful for stored last edit information. This only works with timestamp, not datetime however.

Answer (score 28):

I would always use a Unix timestamp when working with MySQL and PHP. The main reason for this being the default [date](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) method in PHP uses a timestamp as the parameter, so there would be no parsing needed.

To get the current Unix timestamp in PHP, just do `time();`
and in MySQL do `SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP();`.

Comment: -1 I actually think the answer below is better - using datetime allows you to push more logic for date processing into MySQL itself, which can be very useful.

Comment: Haven't there been benchmarks showing that sorting in MySQL is slower than in php?

Comment: well it depends, sometimes it good to use it when we like to not use strtotime. ( php5.3 dep )

Comment: you can push the logic into mysql by just using FROM_UNIXTIME if needed

Comment: I used to use all Unix timestamps in my PHP applications and in MySQL, however I have found it's a lot more convenient to store dates and times in MySQL as native date/time types. This is especially useful for reporting purposes and just browsing data sets. Over time as I got frustrated having to copy/past Unix timestamps I started switching. 

I'm quite certain there are performance and other pros/cons, but depending on your use case convenience can be more important than fairly micro-optimizations.

Answer (score 20):

From my experiences, if you want a date field in which insertion happens only once and you don't want to have any update or any other action on that particular field, go with **date time**.

For example, consider a `user` table with a **REGISTRATION DATE** field. In that `user` table, if you want to know the last logged in time of a particular user, go with a field of **timestamp** type so that the field gets updated.

If you are creating the table from [phpMyAdmin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpMyAdmin) the default setting will update the **timestamp** field when a row update happens. If your timestamp filed is not updating with row update, you can use the following query to make a **timestamp** field get auto updated.

```
ALTER TABLE your_table
      MODIFY COLUMN ts_activity TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Answer (score 17):

The timestamp data type stores date and time, but in UTC format, not in the current timezone format as datetime does. And when you fetch data, timestamp again converts that into the current timezone time.

So suppose you are in USA and getting data from a server which has a time zone of USA. Then you will get the date and time according to the USA time zone. The timestamp data type column always get updated automatically when its row gets updated. So it can be useful to track when a particular row was updated last time.

For more details you can read the blog post *[Timestamp Vs Datetime](http://codebucket.co.in/timestamp-vs-datetime/)* .

Comment: You can (should) always define the timezone at the session level with `SET time_zone = '+0:00';` (UTC here) to be sure what you get/set from `TIMESTAMP` values and avoid depending on the server time_zone default which might change.

Answer (score 17):

Beware of timestamp changing when you do a UPDATE statement on a table.  If you have a table with columns 'Name' (varchar), 'Age' (int), and 'Date_Added' (timestamp) and you run the following DML statement

```
UPDATE table
SET age = 30
```

then every single value in your 'Date_Added' column would be changed to the current timestamp.

Comment: based on how you setup your table you can control this behavior.  look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Comment: @CharlesFaiga The default behavior is for the timestamp to update when any other column is updated.  You have to explicitly turn this off if you want the timestamp to retain its original value

Comment: What is that ?! you must be set the timstamp column to `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: This is a _feature_ that you have to enable explicitely when creating the table.

Comment: I feel lucky to have read this answer

Answer (score 16):

I always use a Unix timestamp, simply to maintain sanity when dealing with a lot of datetime information, especially when performing adjustments for timezones, adding/subtracting dates, and the like. When comparing timestamps, this excludes the complicating factors of timezone and allows you to spare resources in your server side processing (Whether it be application code or database queries) in that you make use of light weight arithmetic rather then heavier date-time add/subtract functions.

Another thing worth considering:

If you're building an application, you never know how your data might have to be used down the line. If you wind up having to, say, compare a bunch of records in your data set, with, say, a bunch of items from a third-party API, and say, put them in chronological order, you'll be happy to have Unix timestamps for your rows. Even if you decide to use MySQL timestamps, store a Unix timestamp as insurance.

Answer (score 16):

[Reference taken from this Article:](http://www.dbrnd.com/2015/09/difference-between-datetime-and-timestamp-in-mysql/)

**The main differences:**

TIMESTAMP used to track changes to records, and update every time when the record is changed.
DATETIME used to store specific and static value which is not affected by any changes in records.

TIMESTAMP also affected by different TIME ZONE related setting.
DATETIME is constant.

TIMESTAMP internally converted current time zone to UTC for storage, and during retrieval converted back to the current time zone.
DATETIME can not do this.

TIMESTAMP supported range:
‘1970-01-01 00:00:01′ UTC to ‘2038-01-19 03:14:07′ UTC
DATETIME supported range:
‘1000-01-01 00:00:00′ to ‘9999-12-31 23:59:59′

Answer (score 16):

In my case, I set UTC as a time zone for everything: the system, the database server, etc. every time that I can. If my customer requires another time zone, then I configure it on the app.

I almost always prefer timestamps rather than datetime fields, because timestamps include the timezone implicitly. So, since the moment that the app will be accessed from users from different time zones and you want them to see dates and times in their local timezone, this field type makes it pretty easy to do it than if the data were saved in datetime fields.

As a plus, in the case of a migration of the database to a system with another timezone, I would feel more confident using timestamps. Not to say possible issues when calculating differences between two moments with a sumer time change in between and needing a precision of 1 hour or less.

So, to summarize, I value this advantages of timestamp:

- ready to use on international (multi time zone) apps
- easy migrations between time zones
- pretty easy to calculate diferences (just subtract both timestamps)
- no worry about dates in/out a summer time period

For all this reasons, I choose UTC & timestamp fields where posible. And I avoid headaches ;)

Comment: timestamp data will be fun for the person supporting your application when January 20, 2038 arrives.  tick tock tick tock

Comment: Timestamp type could then be increased by a bit and double the possible values.

Comment: Test your theory to 'increase by a bit' and see if you can successfully store February 1, 2038 and retrieve it with MySQL.  Let's see your table definition when finished, please.  You are probably going to have a lot of unhappy past acquaintances in February, 2038.

Comment: @WilsonHauck You'll have to upgrade the MySQL version long before 2038 anyway. And that extended TIMESTAMP will be handled by the migration. Also, few applications besides handling mortgages really need to care about 2038 right now.

Comment: @dolmen lots of professional-grade tools and materials have a 20+ year warranty. So something like `warranties.expires_at` could not be a MySQL timestamp today.

Answer (score 14):

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                       TIMESTAMP                                       |                                 DATETIME                                 |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| TIMESTAMP requires 4 bytes.                                                           | DATETIME requires 8 bytes.                                               |
| Timestamp is the number of seconds that have elapsed since January 1, 1970 00:00 UTC. | DATETIME is a text displays 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format.                |
| TIMESTAMP supported range: ‘1970-01-01 00:00:01′ UTC to ‘2038-01-19 03:14:07′ UTC.    | DATETIME supported range: ‘1000-01-01 00:00:00′ to ‘9999-12-31 23:59:59′ |
| TIMESTAMP during retrieval converted back to the current time zone.                   | DATETIME can not do this.                                                |
| TIMESTAMP is used mostly for metadata i.e. row created/modified and audit purpose.    | DATETIME is used mostly for user-data.                                   |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 12):

I found unsurpassed usefulness in TIMESTAMP's ability to auto update itself based on the current time without the use of unnecessary triggers. That's just me though, although TIMESTAMP is UTC like it was said.

It can keep track across different timezones, so if you need to display a relative time for instance, UTC time is what you would want.

Answer (score 12):

DATETIME vs TIMESTAMP:

TIMESTAMP used to track changes of records, and update every time when the record is changed.

DATETIME used to store specific and static value which is not affected by any changes in records.

TIMESTAMP also affected by different TIME ZONE related setting.
DATETIME is constant.

TIMESTAMP internally converted a current time zone to UTC for storage, and during retrieval convert the back to the current time zone.

DATETIME can not do this.

TIMESTAMP is 4 bytes and DATETIME is 8 bytes.

TIMESTAMP supported range:
‘1970-01-01 00:00:01′ UTC to ‘2038-01-19 03:14:07′ UTC
DATETIME supported range:
‘1000-01-01 00:00:00′ to ‘9999-12-31 23:59:59′

Answer (score 11):

I stopped using `datetime` in my applications after facing many problems and bugs related to time zones. **IMHO using `timestamp` is better than `datetime` in most of the cases**.

When you ask what is the time ? and the answer comes as something like '2019-02-05 21:18:30', that is not completed, not defined answer because it lacks another part, in which timezone  ? Washington ? Moscow ? Beijing ?

Using datetimes without the timezone means that your application is dealing with only 1 timezone, however timestamps give you the benefits of `datetime` plus the flexibility of showing the same exact point of time in different timezones.

Here are some cases that will make you regret using `datetime` and wish that you stored your data in timestamps.

1. For your clients comfort you want to show them the times based on their preferred time zones without making them doing the math and convert the time to their meaningful timezone. all you need is to change the timezone and all your application code will be the same.*(Actually you should always define the timezone at the start of the application, or request processing in case of PHP applications)*

   ```
   SET time_zone = '+2:00';
   ```
2. you changed the country you stay in, and continue your work of maintaining the data while seeing it in a different timezone (without changing the actual data).
3. you accept data from different clients around the world, each of them inserts the time in his timezone.

### In short

`datetime` = application supports 1 timezone (for both inserting and selecting)

`timestamp` = application supports any timezone (for both inserting and selecting)

---

*This answer is only for putting some highlight on the flexibility and ease of timestamps when it comes to time zones , it is not covering any other differences like the [column size or range or fraction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45632196/5407848).*

Comment: what if there are fields that use `date`, and other field uses `timestamp` in one table. I think it will cause a new problem because the data that is filtered by `where` is not in accordance with Timezone changes.

Comment: @ErlangP In that case your application should fix the timezone problem on the `date` column before sending the query.

Answer (score 10):

The major difference is

- a INDEX's on Timestamp  - works
- a INDEX's on Datetime   - [Does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013301/mysql-datetime-index-is-not-working)

look at this [post to see problems with Datetime indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95183/how-does-one-create-an-index-on-the-date-part-of-datetime-field-in-mysql)

Comment: Both have the same issue if you're selecting with a function based on the column value, and both can be indexed.

Comment: Index works on timestamp and does not work on datetime? You drew wrong conclusions from those posts.

Answer (score 9):

I prefer using timestamp so to keep everything in one common raw format and format the data in PHP code or in your SQL query. There are instances where it comes in handy in your code to keep everything in plain seconds.

Answer (score 9):

Another difference between Timestamp and Datetime is in Timestamp you can't default value to NULL.

Comment: It is obviously wrong. [Here is an example:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

`CREATE TABLE t2 (
  ts1 TIMESTAMP NULL,
  ts2 TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
                ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);` The first column can accept NULL value.

Answer (score 7):

A `TIMESTAMP` requires 4 bytes, whereas a `DATETIME` requires 8 bytes.

Comment: "As of MySQL 5.6.4, storage for YEAR and DATE remains unchanged. However...DATETIME is packed more efficiently, requiring 5 rather than 8 bytes", so a difference of 1 byte between timestamp and datetime, with timestamp "expiring" just around the corner in 2038 :)

From the docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-date-time

Answer (score 6):

I like a Unix timestamp, because you can convert to numbers and just worry about the number. Plus you add/subtract and get durations, etc. Then convert the result to Date in whatever format. This code finds out how much time in minutes passed between a timestamp from a document, and the current time.

```
$date  = $item['pubdate']; (etc ...)
$unix_now = time();
$result = strtotime($date, $unix_now);
$unix_diff_min = (($unix_now  - $result) / 60);
$min = round($unix_diff_min);
```

Comment: Or, use a human readeable and native MySQL datetime, and use native MySQL functions to add / substract datetimes.

Answer (score 6):

TIMESTAMP is useful when you have visitors from different countries with different time zones. you can easily convert the TIMESTAMP to any country time zone

Answer (score 5):

A `DATETIME` carries no timezone information with it and will always display the same independent of the timezone that is in effect for the session, which defaults to the server's timezone unless you have explicitly changed it. However, if I initialize a `DATETIME` column with a function such as `NOW()` rather than a literal such as `'2020-01-16 12:15:00'`, then the value stored will, of course, be the current date and time localized to the session's timezone.

A `TIMESTAMP` by contrast does implicitly carry timezone information: When you initialize a  `TIMESTAMP` column with a value, that value is converted to UTC before it is stored. If the value being stored is a literal such as `'2020-01-16 12:15:00'`, it is interpreted as being in the session's current timezone for conversion purposes. Conversely, when a `TIMESTAMP` column is displayed, it will first be converted from UTC to the session's current timezone.

**When to use one or the other? A Case Study**

A Website for a community theater group is presenting several performances of a play for which it is selling tickets. The dates and times of these performances will appear in a drop down from which a customer wishing to buy tickets for a performance will select one. It would make sense for database column `performance_date_and_time` to be a `DATETIME` type. If the performance is in New York, there is an understanding that there is an implicit timezone involved ("New York local time") and ideally we would want the date and time to display as 'December 12, 2019 at 8:00 PM' regardless of the session's timezone and without having to go to the trouble of having to do any timezone conversions.

On the other hand, once the December 12th, 2019 8 PM performance began, we might no longer want to sell tickets for it and thus no longer display that performance in the drop down. So, we would like to be able to know whether '2019-12-12 20:00:00' has occurred or not. That would argue for having a `TIMESTAMP` column, setting the timezone for the session to 'America/New_York' with `set session time_zone='America/New_York'` and then storing `'2019-12-12 20:00:00'` into the `TIMESTAMP` column. Henceforth we can test for whether the performance has begun by comparing this column with `NOW()` independent of the current session timezone.

Or it might make sense to have a `DATETIME` and a `TIMESTAMP` column for these two separate purposes. Or not. Clearly, either one could serve both purposes. If you go with just a `DATETIME` column, then you must set the current timezone to your local timezone before comparing with `NOW()`. If you go with just a `TIMESTAMP` column, you must set the session timezone to your local timezone before displaying the column.

Comment: What matters for TIMESTAMP values but also MySQL date/time functions is not the _server_ `time_zone` but the _session_ `time_zone` (which defaults to the _server_ `time_zone` until changed explicitely). Never rely in your app on a default that might change.

Comment: @dolmen Of course you are correct but we are talking semantics. I say in my answer, `"... setting the the server's timezone for the session ...".` Perhaps it could have been expressed more clearly by just saying "setting the timezone for the session",but in the end this will be the timezone that the server will be using. I will update the answer to make this clearer.

Answer (score 4):

I merely use unsigned `BIGINT` while storing UTC ...

which then still can be adjusted to local time in PHP.

the `DATETIME` to be selected with `FROM_UNIXTIME( integer_timestamp_column )`.

one obviously should set an index on that column, else there would be no advance.

Answer (score 3):

A lot of answers here suggest to store as timestamp in the case you have to represent well defined points in time. But you can also have points in time with datetime if you store them all in UTC by convention.

Comment: Can you give some reasons why I should prefer this instead of using timestamp?

Comment: @Jasir not really, it seems a big debate. I was only pointing out that datetime can represent specific points in time if there is a convention to store all datetimes in a specific timezone (i.e. UTC). Personally, I would store everything in datetime, timestamp being limited to 2038 (even though I guess they will eventually do something about it), and if I look at some raw data in DB, datetime will be readable without having to apply conversion. Again, this is very subjective.

Comment: @Matthew But if the session `time_zone` is not `UTC` too, you will have surprises (bugs) if you use MySQL date/time functions such as `NOW()`, `DATE_ADD` without converting timezone first... So why make database interaction more complicated than necessary?

Comment: @dolmen the idea is that server-side everything is UTC. MySQL session time zone included. This should be set as the server's time zone which should be UTC

Answer (score 3):

Not mentioned so far, is that DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP only works with Timestamp, but not DateTime type fields.

This becomes relevant for MS Access tables which can only use DateTime but not Timestamp.

Comment: The `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` support for a `DATETIME` is added in MySQL 5.6.

Comment: "Any of the synonyms for `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` have the same meaning as `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. These are `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), NOW(), LOCALTIME, LOCALTIME(), LOCALTIMESTAMP`, and `LOCALTIMESTAMP()`." -> [mysql docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to GUARANTEE your application will NOT function in February, 2038, use TIMESTAMP.   Refer to your REFMAN for the RANGE of dates supported.

Comment: 2038 is so far that you will have changed the MySQL server version to one that supports extended TIMESTAMP long before. And this also assumes your application will still be in use.

Answer (score 1):

The **DATETIME** type is used for values containing date and time parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIMEvalues in format. The supported range is . **'YYYYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'** **'1000-01-01 00:00:00''9999-12-31 23:59:59'**

The **TIMESTAMP** data type is used for values containing date and time parts. **TIMESTAMP** has a range from **'1970-01-01 00:00:01'UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07'UTC.**

```
mysql> SELECT col,
     >     CAST(col AT TIME ZONE INTERVAL '+00:00' AS DATETIME) AS ut
     >     FROM ts ORDER BY id;
+---------------------+---------------------+
| col                 | ut                  |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2020-01-01 10:10:10 | 2020-01-01 15:10:10 |
| 2019-12-31 23:40:10 | 2020-01-01 04:40:10 |
| 2020-01-01 13:10:10 | 2020-01-01 18:10:10 |
| 2020-01-01 10:10:10 | 2020-01-01 15:10:10 |
| 2020-01-01 04:40:10 | 2020-01-01 09:40:10 |
| 2020-01-01 18:10:10 | 2020-01-01 23:10:10 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

**URL MySQL 8.0 :** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html

Answer (score 0):

`timestamp` is a current time of an event recorded by a computer through **Network Time Protocol (NTP)**.

`datetime` is a current timezone that is set in your **PHP** configuration.

Comment: No. Unrelated to NTP.

Comment: And in 2039, use of timestamp will ensure your application will not be functioning.