# What are good reasons to choose TIMESTAMP over DATETIME columns in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, timestamp

Disclaimer: This might be a duplicate of [datetime vs. timestamp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/datetime-vs-timestamp), but I feel I am not convinced of the answers:

My question is:
**What are the good reasons to choose TIMESTAMP over DATETIME columns in MySQL?**

I'm pretty sure I don't know everything there is about the differences between those two, so I will try to list the main advantages of DATETIME (`DT`) compared to TIMESTAMP (`TS`) to my knowledge:

- `DT` is human readable (`TS` is not without using `TO_DATE`)
- `DT` has a possble timespan of 8999 Years (`1000-01-01 00:00:00` to `9999-12-31 23:59:59`)
  (`TS` only about 68 years, `1970-01-01` to `2038-01-19`)
- `DT` fields seem to perform better (according to [this blog post](http://dbscience.blogspot.com/2008/08/can-timestamp-be-slower-than-datetime.html))
- `DT` can be used for advanced date calculation (`SELECT NOW() + INTERVAL 2 DAY`)

And vice versa:

- `TS` only needs 4 bytes (`DT` uses 8)
- `TS` are stored as UTC values and changed according to the client's timezone setting
- `TS` columns can serve as a "log" for monitoring when a row has changes

The only reason I see for using it then would be the row monitoring, but looking at the range of `TIMESTAMP`, which will end in "only" 28 years*, I would rather go with an insert or update trigger.

So, what am I missing? I still don't see a *really good* reason for choosing timestamp for any purpose?

<sub>* I know, this is appears quite long, but back in the 60s some engineers also decided to shave off 2 bytes of the year field, because their computer systems *would never* run until the year 2000 .....</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DT columns can also serve as a "log" for monitoring when a row changes, I use them and triggers to do that.

I usually use timestamp when working with a lot of PHP stuff as to cut down on too much date parsing. If the need ever arises, I can update my software to use datetime.

Answer (score 2):

The main question is: what is the purpose of dateime/timestamp field? If it is just a timestamp like in a log file where you only store the actual time the timestam is the better choice. Because it needs only 4 bytes and we are in the scope what the timestamp can cover it. If it is a date like date of birth the datetime is the good choice. We hope we'll have solution before end of timestamp scope. ;) (Sorry for my English).

Comment: I agree with the storage required, but the speed gain when using DATETIME seems to outweigh this, especially when you're searching for an event on a specific date.

Comment: `We hope we'll have solution before end of timestamp scope`. I guess we will have a nice media rant around mid January 2038 :-).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a funny aspect of DT which I already used:
Using DT - at least in MySQL - you have the option of leaving either the year at "0000", and/or both month and day: "00-00".
This comes in handy for storing birthday dates without requiring complete information!

Comment: True; it does, however, come in less than handy if you later need to copy / migrate data to a different DBMS that requires date fields to actually contain (real) dates. Been there, done that...