# Bulk convert and update datetime column values to UNIX timestamp?

Tags: php, mysql

**Background**

I have a MySQL db with around 16 million records. There are 2 columns `created_at` and `updated_at` which are presently in `datetime` format.

**The Problem**

I'd like to change this to `UNIX Timestamp` by converting all the values and updating the records with the new values.

I know how to do this with PHP in loops, but is there a way to perform this update by executing a single query in MySQL?

Comment: Two reasons; 1 for the learning aspect; and 2, because I think it'll save me 250+ MB in storage plus an equal amount in Index. And as I work with flaky internet connections, offline backups from the cloud will be slighly easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it'll be a one time change; you can proceed this way:

1. Create new columns with `INT` datatypes and name them, say, `created` and `updated`.

   ```
   ALTER TABLE `nameOfTable`
       ADD COLUMN `created` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' AFTER `created_at`,
       ADD COLUMN `updated` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' AFTER `updated_at`;
   ```
2. Update table:

   ```
   UPDATE `nameOfTable`
   SET `created` = UNIX_TIMESTAMP( `created_at` ),
       `updated` = UNIX_TIMESTAMP( `updated_at` );
   ```
3. Remove the older columns and rename newer ones back to `created_at` and `updated_at`.

---

Alternative way:

1. Set the `DATETIME` columns to `VARCHAR` field.
2. Update using the query:

   ```
   UPDATE `nameOfTable`
   SET `created_at` = UNIX_TIMESTAMP( `created_at` ),
       `updated_at` = UNIX_TIMESTAMP( `updated_at` );
   ```
3. Change the columns to `INT`.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! Incidentally, does saving in the timestamp format save much space over 16mn records?

Comment: @Reddox http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533767/mysql-whats-the-best-to-use-unix-timestamp-or-datetime and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948494/unix-timestamp-vs-datetime

Comment: 2nd query's pretty nifty. Thanks again!

Comment: If you're going to ever want milli or microseconds you should probably go "BIGINT" (64-bit, same as java long and c# long/int64) for your column type, plus 2038 is just around the corner. :)

Answer (score 0):

hjpotter92's answer helped a lot.

But in my case it did not solve the problem right away, since the dates I had stored were in a format not accepted as an argument by UNIX_TIMESTAMP.

So I had to first convert it to an accepted format. After some research I got to the following query that made it:

```
UPDATE tableName set newFieldName = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(CAST(priorFieldName AS CHAR), '%m/%d/%y'));
```