# mysql - converting datetime column to timestamp

Tags: mysql, datetime

I am trying to convert datetime columns of my database to timestamp without data loss. I followed this answer:
[Bulk convert and update datetime column values to UNIX timestamp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351106/bulk-convert-and-update-datetime-column-values-to-unix-timestamp)

but when I want to:

```
UPDATE `members` SET `new_join_date` = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`join_date`), `new_last_visit` = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`last_visit`);
```

I get this error:

```
#1292 - Incorrect datetime value: '1376833381' for column 'new_join_date' at row 1
```

full convertion queries:

```
ALTER TABLE `members`
ADD COLUMN `new_join_date` TIMESTAMP NULL AFTER `join_date`,
ADD COLUMN `new_last_visit` TIMESTAMP NULL AFTER `last_visit`;

UPDATE `members`
SET `new_join_date` = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`join_date`),
`new_last_visit` = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`last_visit`);

ALTER TABLE `members` DROP `join_date`;

ALTER TABLE `members` DROP `last_visit`;

ALTER TABLE `members` CHANGE `new_join_date` `join_date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

ALTER TABLE `members` CHANGE `new_last_visit` `last_visit` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL `TIMESTAMP` and `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`  are not the same type!

You declared `new_join_date` and `new_last_visit` to be of type TIMESTAMP and then try to set it to a different type, hence the error.

To work around it you should declare these columns as `INT(11)`.

Comment: but I need that columns to be TIMESTAMP type not INT.

Comment: @exim then you can't store the date in unix format in those columns!