# Is it better to convert date in Mysql or PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, date-formatting

I have timestamps stored in `datetime` columns in a Mysql database. 
The timestamps are already in UTC time.

My PHP application needs to return the values in ISO 8601 format.

Is it better to convert them using PHP ex:

```
date('c', strtotime($sqldata['my_date_field']));
```

Or using MySql's `DATE_FORMAT` function? ex:

```
DATE_FORMAT(my_date_field,'%Y-%m-%dT%TZ')
```

I'm trying to consider speed, accuracy, and best practice.

Comment: Store your values in unix time. If you insist on storing them as datetime then use whichever one you are more familiar with and don't mind debugging.

Comment: PHP - that way you can convert to other formats for display, extract parts (e.g., just date or just time), convert to local timezone, etc. The time to convert the date from one format to another - whether in MySQL or PHP - is extremely small.

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533767/mysql-whats-the-best-to-use-unix-timestamp-or-datetime