# Remove on update condition without drop mysql table

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a mysql table and data entries in it:

```
CREATE TABLE    `invoices`.`invoices` (
    `InvoiceID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `UserID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `Value` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL,
    `Description` varchar(4048) NOT NULL,
    `DateTime` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY    (`InvoiceID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin5;
```

I want to remove "on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" condition. How can I alter this table?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE `invoices`.`invoices`
    CHANGE `DateTime` `DateTime` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: I only want to remove on update condition. Because I dont want DateTime to be updated on record update.

Comment: I edited it, now it should default to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` on new insertions, but stays as is on update.

Comment: If you want to remove the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP setting when inserting too, use the above query, but replace the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP with "0000-00-00 00:00:00" (including the ")

Comment: This worked for me, 
alter table tmpx change `ts` `ts` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
CREATE TABLE `tmpx` (
  `ts` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ;
insert into tmpx values(null, null);

Answer (score 8):

aularon's ans will not remove the on update condition

It can be removed by using the following 2 commands :

```
ALTER TABLE `invoices`.`invoices`
    CHANGE `DateTime` `DateTime` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;

ALTER TABLE `invoices`.`invoices`
    CHANGE `DateTime` `DateTime` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

**Note**:  This will work only in MySQL and not on SQL Server

Comment: Have you tried them yourself? They both yield SQL syntax errors.

Comment: Yes I have tried. DateTime is column name. please check properly

Answer (score 1):

For your use case I think you would be better served with `DATETIME`, eg:

```
ALTER TABLE `my_table`
    CHANGE `my_col` `my_col` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW();
```

This will default to `NOW()` on insert, but remain unaffected on update.

See this question for a good explanation of the difference: [Should I use field 'datetime' or 'timestamp'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/should-i-use-field-datetime-or-timestamp)

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE `invoices` CHANGE `DateTime` `DateTime` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE `invoices` CHANGE `DateTime` `DateTime` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: While answers are always appreciated, this question was asked 6 **years** ago, and already had an accepted solution. Please try to avoid 'bumping' questions to the top by providing answers to them, unless the question was not already marked as resolved, or you found a new and improved solution to the problem. Also remember to provide some [**context surrounding your code**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762) to help explain it. Check out the documentation on [**writing great answers**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for some tips on how to make your answers count :)