# Do indexes speed up greater than > comparison in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have an events tables in my db, which includes among others start_date and end_date columns.

I frequently run queries like

```
where start_date > 'some starting date' and end_date < 'some end date'
```

Will I benefit from adding an index to the start_date and end_date columns? I figure out that this is not a = comparison, but maybe anyway.

Comment: Try running an explain on your query before and after indexing it.

Comment: In short: If your query returns only a few rows because of this condition then the index is useful.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12957781/indexing-sql-for-between-query-with-only-one-match

Comment: That formulation checks for being "entirely withing", whereas a similar formulation checks for "overlapping":  `start < "end" and end > "start".  Which do you want to discuss?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The MySQL optimizer will use the indexes where it thinks it is appropriate to do so:

> A B-tree index can be used for column comparisons in expressions that
>   use the =, >, >=, <, <=, or BETWEEN operators.
>
> ...
>
> Sometimes MySQL does not use an index, even if one is available. One
>   circumstance under which this occurs is when the optimizer estimates
>   that using the index would require MySQL to access a very large
>   percentage of the rows in the table. (In this case, a table scan is
>   likely to be much faster because it requires fewer seeks.)

Source: [Comparison of B-Tree and Hash Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-btree-hash.html)

You might find these interesting:

[How MySQL Uses Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-indexes.html)

And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691799/why-does-mysql-not-use-an-index-for-a-greater-than-comparison#4691851) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691799/why-does-mysql-not-use-an-index-for-a-greater-than-comparison#4691996) to [Why does MySQL not use an index for a greater than comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691799/why-does-mysql-not-use-an-index-for-a-greater-than-comparison).

Comment: The "very large percentage" is typically 10% to 30%, in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, database will use those indexes and it should increase performance.

Note: it cannot use the two disctinct indexes simultaneously for good performance you need a [multi-column index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html).

Comment: An index _may_ be used.  A multi-column index won't help -- because both columns need to be compared via a range check.

Comment: @RickJames what's better, < 5 or IN (0, 1, 2, 3, 4) for int column?

Comment: @Andrew - It depends on the rest of the query.  I can think of situations where `<` would be faster, or `IN` would be faster, or they would be the same.  Start a new Question with specific queries and `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the tables used.  A partial answer is in my [_Index Cookbook_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

Comment: @RickJames I read your cookbook and did not find any partial answer in there regarding '<' vs 'IN'. Take the most simple query if you wish, only one condition, either one or another.

Comment: @Andrew - My apologies.  That info was 'left on the cutting room floor'.  I added some "Misc" to my Answer.  To address your specific Comment:  "< 5" is not likely to be any faster than `IN(...)`.  I would be happy to see any specific cases to the contrary, together with `CREATE` and `EXPLAIN`.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend having these two composite indexes:

```
INDEX(start_date, end_date),
INDEX(end_date, start_date)
```

However, they may not be as beneficial as you would like.  This is because there is no good way to use an index on more than one "range".

If the ranges do not overlap, then there is a somewhat complex technique to make the certain queries quite fast:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ipranges

**Misc**

(A semi-related comment on which things are more optimizable.)

These are in order of how optimizable they are

- Equal: `=`, `IS NULL`, `LIKE 'abc'` (no wildcards), `IN (only-one-item)`
- IN:  `IN (multiple-items)` (see also the equivalent `OR`)
- Range: '>' (etc), `BETWEEN..AND..`, `LIKE 'abc%'` (wildcard, but not at start), `IS NOT NULL`
- Un-optimizable:  `LIKE '%xyz'` (leading wildcard), unsargable (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable)), `NOT anything` `REGEXP`