# Why doesn't MySql automatically optimises BETWEEN query?

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization

I have two query for same output

**Slow Query:**

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    account_range
WHERE
    is_active = 1 AND '8033576667466317' BETWEEN range_start AND range_end;
```

Execution Time: **~800 ms**.

Explain:

```
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+------+-------------------------------------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table         | partitions | type | possible_keys                             | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+------+-------------------------------------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | account_range | NULL       | ALL  | range_start,range_end,range_se_active_idx | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 940712 |     2.24 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+------+-------------------------------------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------------+
```

**Very Fast Query:** [learnt from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12964468/1644614)

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    account_range
WHERE
    is_active = 1 AND 
    range_start = (SELECT 
            MAX(range_start)
        FROM
            account_range
        WHERE
            range_start <= '8033576667466317') AND 
    range_end = (SELECT 
            MIN(range_end)
        FROM
            account_range
        WHERE
            range_end >= '8033576667466317')
```

Execution Time: **~1ms**

Explain:

```
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+------+-------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+-------------------+------+----------+------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table         | partitions | type | possible_keys                             | key                 | key_len | ref               | rows | filtered | Extra                        |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+------+-------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+-------------------+------+----------+------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | account_range | NULL       | ref  | range_start,range_end,range_se_active_idx | range_se_active_idx | 125     | const,const,const |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                         |
|  3 | SUBQUERY    | NULL          | NULL       | NULL | NULL                                      | NULL                | NULL    | NULL              | NULL |     NULL | Select tables optimized away |
|  2 | SUBQUERY    | NULL          | NULL       | NULL | NULL                                      | NULL                | NULL    | NULL              | NULL |     NULL | Select tables optimized away |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+------+-------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+-------------------+------+----------+------------------------------+
```

Table Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE account_range (
    id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    range_start varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    range_end varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    is_active tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
    bank_name varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
    addedon timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updatedon timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    description text,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    KEY range_start (range_start),
    KEY range_end (range_end),
    KEY range_se_active_idx (range_start , range_end , is_active)
)  ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=946132 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Please do explain Why doesn't MySql automatically optimizes **BETWEEN** query?

**Update:**
Realised my mistake from @kordirko answer. My table contains only `non-overlapping` ranges, so both queries are returning same results.

Comment: Do things improve without the inverted commas? Try removing the range start and range end indexes

Comment: Do both queries return the same rows? Because from what I see, depending on the real date you have in the tables, they might give different results...

Comment: Changing the order in index range_se_active_idx  to (is_active, range_start , range_end) might improve the performance of the first query

Comment: @piotrgajow: output is same for both queries.

Comment: @Strawberry: If I remove inverted comma, then it will be treated as integer, but it is a string.

Comment: In what sense is one string 'between' another?

Comment: @Strawberry if after sorting using given collation it is between another ones :)

Comment: @AtulVaibhav So every row returned by both queries has the same combination of values of range_start and range_end?

Comment: The simple answer is that MySQL cannot assume that start..end pairs do not overlap.  See @kordirko's answer for an example.

Comment: This question is virtually a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12957781/indexing-sql-for-between-query-with-only-one-match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a comparision doesn't make sense, since you are comparing apples to oranges.
These two queries are not eqivalent, they give different resuts,
 thus MySql optimises them in a different way and their plans can differ.

See this simple example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/98678/2

```
create table account_range(
  is_active int,
  range_start int,
  range_end int
 );

 insert into account_range values
 (1,-20,100), (1,10,30);
```

First query gives 2 rows:

```
select * from account_range
 where is_active = 1 and 25 between range_start AND range_end;

| is_active | range_start | range_end |
|-----------|-------------|-----------|
|         1 |         -20 |       100 |
|         1 |          10 |        30 |
```

Second query gives only 1 row:

```
SELECT * FROM account_range
WHERE
    is_active = 1 AND 
    range_start = (SELECT MAX(range_start)
                   FROM account_range
                   WHERE range_start <= 25
    ) AND 
    range_end = (SELECT MIN(range_end)
                 FROM account_range
                 WHERE range_end >= 25
    )

| is_active | range_start | range_end |
|-----------|-------------|-----------|
|         1 |          10 |        30 |
```

---

To speed this query up (the first one), two bitmap indexes can be used together with "bitmap and" operation - but MySql doesn't have such a feature.
Another option is a spatial index (for example GIN indexes in PostgreSql: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-indexes.html).
And another option is a star transformation (or a star schema) - you need to "divide" this table into two "dimension" or "measures" tables and one "fact" table .... but this is too broad topic, if you want know more you can start from here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema

Comment: I'll bet you could add another row to that table and zero 0 rows!  The "fast" query depends on certain properties of start...end.

Comment: If my data only contains only non overlapping ranges then what are my options to optimise this query, I am ready to explore other options than Mysql.

Answer (score 1):

Second query is fast because MySQL is able to use available index.

```
SELECT * FROM account_range
WHERE
   is_active = 1 AND 
   range_start = a_constant_value_1 AND 
   range_end = a_constant_value_2
```

Above query is fast because `range_se_active_idx` index can satisfy search criteria so it is used.

Both subqueries are also fast (see `Select tables optimized away` in EXPLAIN's output)

```
   SELECT MAX(range_start) FROM account_range
    WHERE range_start <= '8033576667466317'

   SELECT MIN(range_end) FROM account_range
    WHERE range_end >= '8033576667466317'
```

because `range_start` and `range_end` both are indexed, they are ordered.

With ordered data, for first sub query, MySQL basically just picks one record whose `range_start` equals `8033576667466317` or one below it (`MAX(range_start)`). For second sub query, MySQL picks one record whose `range_end` equals `8033576667466317` or one above it (`MIN(range_end)`).

For `BETWEEN ... AND ..` query, MySQL cannot find any indices because that is not a range search. It's basically same as

```
SELECT * FROM account_range
WHERE
  is_active = 1 AND 
  range_start >= '8033576667466317' AND
  range_end <= '8033576667466317';
```

It has to search records with `range_start` from `8033576667466317` to largest value and also from smallest `range_end` to `8033576667466317`. All indices cannot satisfy this criteria so it has to scan table.

I believe it can be optimized if you can rewrite it into something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM account_range
WHERE
  is_active = 1 AND 
  (range_start BETWEEN a_min_value AND a_max_value) AND
  (range_end BETWEEN a_min_value AND a_max_value);
```

Comment: My doubt is in the part where you said "between" query is same as "range_start >= '803...7' AND range_end <= '803...7' ".  So why didn't Mysql just replaced '803...7' with "a_constant_value_1" and "a_constant_value_2" respectively just the way it is computing them in faster query ?

Comment: The problem is, that one query checks if the values are equal, and the other query checks if one is greater than the other. Those are two completely different constraints, and I am surprised that those two queries give you the same result. Depending on the data the slower one (with between clause) might return more rows then the other one.