# Why does Order By not use composite index?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I have an index on (blog_id, is_published, publication_date).
Why does not

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE blog_id = 403 AND is_published = 1 AND publication_date < '2015-02-13 13:13:00' ORDER BY publication_date LIMIT 1;
```

use all the keys in the composite index ?

Please point out if I am assuming something incorrectly.

Execution plan:

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "ordering_operation": {
      "using_filesort": false,
      "table": {
        "table_name": "t",
        "access_type": "ref",
        "possible_keys": [
          "t_ee664462",
          "t_472bc96c",
          "test"
        ],
        "key": "test",
        "used_key_parts": [
          "blog_id",
          "is_published"
        ],
        "key_length": "5",
        "ref": [
          "const",
          "const"
        ],
        "rows": 47010,
        "filtered": 100,
        "index_condition": "(publication_date < '2015-02-13 13:13:00')",
        "attached_condition": "((`blog_id` <=> 403) and (`is_published` <=> 1))"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is really confusing. I understand that the first two index parts are used (blog_id, is_published), but then with "index_condition" it says that it will filter the index by publication_date.

Also "attached_condition" says that, after the full row is retrieved, it will filter by blog_id and is_published.
I don't understand what I am reading wrong here.

Changing the "order by publication_date" to "order by blog_id, is_published, publication_date" does not make any difference.

If I try

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE blog_id = 403 AND is_published = 1 AND publication_date < '2015-02-13 13:13:00' LIMIT 1;

{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "table": {
      "table_name": "t",
      "access_type": "range",
      "possible_keys": [
        "t_ee664462",
        "t_472bc96c",
        "test"
      ],
      "key": "test",
      "used_key_parts": [
        "blog_id",
        "is_published",
        "publication_date"
      ],
      "key_length": "10",
      "rows": 47010,
      "filtered": 100,
      "index_condition": "((`is_published` = 1) and (`blog_id` = 403) and (`publication_date` < '2015-02-13 13:13:00'))"
    }
  }
}
```

This is what I would expect. The index is filtered by all the key parts before retrieving the full row.

Table information:

```
| Field               | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra       |
| id                  | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| publication_date    | datetime     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| is_published        | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| blog_id             | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
```

Index:

```
| Non_unique | Key_name                                             | Seq_in_index | Column_name       | Collation | Cardinality |
|          1 | test                                                 |            1 | blog_id           | A         |         662 |
|          1 | test                                                 |            2 | is_published      | A         |         912 |
|          1 | test                                                 |            3 | publication_date  | A         |      168864 |
```

168864 is the number of total row and all columns also have simple indexes.

index_condition_pushdown is on.

I had the same results without `Limit 1`.

Reqular explain format:

```
mysql> explain EXTENDED SELECT * FROM t WHERE `blog_id` = 403 AND `is_published` = 1 AND `publication_date` > '2015-02-13 13:13:00' ORDER BY `publication_date`;
+----+-------------+---------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------+-------------+-------+----------+------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                     | type | possible_keys                                                              | key  | key_len | ref         | rows  | filtered | Extra                              |
+----+-------------+---------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------+-------------+-------+----------+------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t | ref  | t_ee664462,t_472bc96c,test | test | 5       | const,const | 64424 |   100.00 | Using index condition; Using where |
+----+-------------+---------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------+-------------+-------+----------+------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)

mysql> explain EXTENDED SELECT * FROM t WHERE `blog_id` = 403 AND `is_published` = 1 AND `publication_date` > '2015-02-13 13:13:00';
+----+-------------+---------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------+-------------+-------+----------+-----------------------+
| id | select_type | table                     | type | possible_keys                                                              | key  | key_len | ref         | rows  | filtered | Extra                 |
+----+-------------+---------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------+-------------+-------+----------+-----------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t | ref  | t_ee664462,t_472bc96c,test | test | 5       | const,const | 64424 |   100.00 | Using index condition |
+----+-------------+---------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------+-------------+-------+----------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: share the explain output of your query please

Comment: I've added the regular `explain extended` output, but I don't see what information it has extra to the `explain output=JSON` already added.

Comment: Maybe related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747359/do-indexes-speed-up-greater-than-comparison-in-mysql ?

Comment: I'd need a better understanding of `index_condition` and `attached_condition` to confirm, but I suspect this could be a quirk of the abstraction between the "SQL" layer and the storage engine layer.  It may be doing as expected, but expressing it strangely (similar to the way fulltext searches always report the estimated rows as "1").  Is performance bad, or is this more of a curiosity?

Comment: @Blag Thanks. It is a little related, but it doesn't answer why `order by  publication_date` make MySQL uses less of the index.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thank you. I'm asking mainly because performance is bad.  If both queries would use the index the same way, the `explain extendend` should say "Using index condition" for both, but the "Order by publication_date" on has "Using index condition; Using where".