# Covering index in MySQL for join + where queries

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization, mariadb

Suppose my query is:

```
SELECT adstable.adid FROM `adstable` 
inner join userstable on 
(adstable.adid = userstable.adid) 
WHERE adstable.desktopimp > 100 
and adstable.mobileimp > 100 
and adstable.userbal > 0.02 
and adstable.realbal> 0.02 
order by adstable.imptotal asc
```

Which columns should I index, to ensure a 'covering index' for this query?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747359/do-indexes-speed-up-greater-than-comparison-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Can there be more than one "user" per "ad"?  Can there be zero?  If neither, then

```
SELECT  a.adid
    FROM  `adstable` AS a
    WHERE  a.desktopimp > 100
      and  a.mobileimp > 100
      and  a.userbal > 0.02
      and  a.realbal> 0.02
      AND  EXISTS (
        SELECT  *
            FROM  userstable
            WHERE  adid = a.adid 
                  )
    order by  a.imptotal asc
```

Whether or not that is a better formulation, have these indexes:

```
userstable:  INDEX(adid)
adstable:    INDEX(imptotal) -- in case it is better to avoid the sort
             INDEX(desktopimp) -- in case it is most selective 
             INDEX(mobileimp)
             INDEX(userbal)
             INDEX(realbal)
```

A "covering" index would include all 6 columns of `adstable` that are used in the query.  That is rather bulky, and of dubious use.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` -- it may be instructive to see the datatypes, engine, etc.

When building an optimal index, start with any columns compared with `=`.  If that takes care of all the `WHERE`, then move on to the `ORDER BY` columns.  You don't have that case, since you are not using `=`.