# Ruby on Rails: why ActiveRecord uses "datetime" type instead of "timestamp" for timestamp fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In my database migration file I inserted the line:

```
t.timestamps
```

Two columns, as I expected, were created: "updated_at" and "created_at". However, their type is "datetime" and not "timestamp".

I am using MySQL and the "timestamp" type, as I understand, [is designed exactly for such cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/datetime-vs-timestamp), as it uses less space and is independent of timezone.

So, is there any reason, why Rails 3 uses "datetime" and not "timestamp"? Should I try to fix that? If yes, is there any way to do this besides not using "t.timestamps" and defining "updated_at" and "created_at" columns separately every time for each new table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From memory, the mysql `timestamp` column type behaves similar to `updated_at` in that it is updated with the current time whenever the record is updated.

While this is useful for the `updated_at` column, this is not the desired behaviour for `created_at`.

In addition, Rails handles the timezone as specified in your app's settings (should would normally be set to UTC), so using mysql's time may be inconsistent with other datetime records.

Answer (score -1):

`timestamp` columns have a limited range which begins in 1970 and ends in 2038. You can google "Unix Millennium Bug" for more information, but it's basically because unix timestamps are stored as a 32-bit signed integer. A timestamp is expressed in seconds since Jan. 1, 1970, and the number wraps on itself in 2038. For this reason, I typically use `datetime` even when `timestamp` seems like an easier solution, especially to represent historical or forecasted data further off into the past or future.