# How to deal with dates in regards to database storage?

Tags: php, mysql, database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [datetime vs timestamp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/datetime-vs-timestamp)

I would like to know how best to store dates in the database.

Do you take a timestamp in the code and save it in an INT field.  Do you take a date and format it to correct format and store it in a DATETIME field?

What are advantages one way or another?  Any good places to read up on the subject?

Thanks for you input!

Comment: Without complete use case you only get subjective answers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would save the date in a datetime field for the following reasons :

- If you happen to work directly on the database (debugging or so) you see dates in a readable format, and you can change values with no manual calculation
- You have date/time functions built in the database that make queries easier to create
- The code will probably be easier to create/maintain (you let others do the work : ie the database)
- If you have to migrate your system to another language/framework/os later, your dates will still be OK, but are you sure that, for a given date, a C# timestamp is the same as a PHP timestamp ?
- What's happening if you move your server to a different time zone ?
- etc..

Many reason I prefer not to handle this myself, and let the clever people do it :-)