# Set NOW() as Default Value for datetime datatype?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, mysql-error-1067

I have two columns in table users namely `registerDate and lastVisitDate` which consist of datetime data type. I would like to do the following.

1. Set registerDate defaults value to MySQL NOW()
2. Set lastVisitDate default value to `0000-00-00 00:00:00` Instead of null which it uses by default.

Because the table already exists and has existing records, I would like to use Modify table.  I've tried using the two piece of code below, but neither works.

```
ALTER TABLE users MODIFY registerDate datetime DEFAULT NOW()
ALTER TABLE users MODIFY registerDate datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

It gives me Error : `ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'registerDate'`

Is it possible for me to set the default datetime value to NOW() in MySQL?

Comment: `ALTER TABLE users MODIFY dateTime timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. You did not defined the `data type` of field in both of your efforts

Comment: Since MySQL 5.6 `DATE` should work with default value `NOW()`

Comment: According to this mysql 5.6 documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/data-type-defaults.html, you can use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() as default.

Comment: how would i implement CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  + 1 DAY

Answer (score 271, accepted):

As of MySQL 5.6.5, you can use the `DATETIME` type with a dynamic default value:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    creation_time      DATETIME DEFAULT   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    modification_time  DATETIME ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

Or even combine both rules:

```
modification_time DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Reference:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html
http://optimize-this.blogspot.com/2012/04/datetime-default-now-finally-available.html

Prior to 5.6.5, you need to use the `TIMESTAMP` data type, which automatically updates whenever the record is modified. Unfortunately, however, only one auto-updated `TIMESTAMP` field can exist per table.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  mydate TIMESTAMP
)
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

If you want to prevent MySQL from updating the timestamp value on `UPDATE` (so that it only triggers on `INSERT`) you can change the definition to:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  mydate TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

Comment: i really don't want to use timestamp.

Comment: @ibrahim, why not?, you state `ALTER TABLE users MODIFY registerDate datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;` as an explicit example in the question.

Comment: @Ibrahim: timestamp is your only chance. If you use a datetime field you have to insert record using now() everytime.

Comment: Manual speaks clear: "This means, for example, that you cannot set the default for a date column to be the value of a function such as NOW() or CURRENT_DATE".

Comment: @Johan `DATETIME` is often prefered to do the range it can hold: '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'  compared to `TIMESTAMPS`'s '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.  For purposes of storing birth dates, or something more than 30 years in the future for instance.

Comment: Also `ALTER TABLE users MODIFY registerDate TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;`

Comment: better link to the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/timestamp-initialization.html which explicitly says that a bare TIMESTAMP column as above gets the "default current_timestamp" and "on update current_timestamp" behaviours.

Comment: there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.  so if you wish use 2 colums, such 'date_created', 'last_edit' - this solution isn`t work

Comment: @nickrulez You no longer are restricted to `timestamp` for this behavior as of MySQL 5.6

Comment: What will be `modification_time ` on the insert? Will it be `NULL`?

Comment: this works

`dateUpdated` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

Answer (score 71):

I use a trigger as a workaround to set a datetime field to NOW() for new inserts:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `triggername` BEFORE INSERT ON  `tablename` 
FOR EACH ROW 
SET NEW.datetimefield = NOW()
```

it should work for updates too

Answers by Johan & Leonardo involve converting to a timestamp field. Although this is probably ok for the use case presented in the question (storing RegisterDate and LastVisitDate), it is not a universal solution. See [datetime vs timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/datetime-vs-timestamp) question.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, but specifically you should edit it to make it obvious it is for a datetime field. The original poster wants to know how to solve it for a datetime field, and `use a timestamp` is a foolish workaround if you really learn the difference between these two data types.

Answer (score 47):

My solution

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` MODIFY COLUMN `column_name` TIMESTAMP NOT
NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Comment: This def works, I recommend everyone to use SQLYog or a tool like that, it lets you do this stuff on a easy interface.

Comment: This is still solution for `TIMESTAMP` column. Nobody was asking for `TIMESTAMP` ...

Comment: Yes, this is not the answer to the question. TIMESTAMP is a different type of field to DATETIME.

Comment: @Leonardo how can i display only date

Answer (score 14):

### **EUREKA !!!**

---

For all those who lost heart trying to set a **default DATETIME value in MySQL**, I know exactly how you feel/felt. So here it is:

```
`ALTER TABLE  `table_name` CHANGE `column_name` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
```

Carefully observe that **I haven't added single quotes/double quotes** around the **0**.

---

**Important update**:

This answer was posted long back. Back then, it worked on my (probably latest) installation of MySQL and I felt like sharing it. Please read the comments below before you decide to use this solution now.

Comment: It depends on expectations...
- This solution allows you to have the field NOT NULL, since a default is provided.
- This solution will not set the field to NOW().

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question; the answer should state that clearly.

Comment: Be aware that the TRADITIONAL SQL mode includes NO_ZERO_DATE, so the above will not work in that case.

Comment: Based on the answers provided, sounds like if you will not sacrifice DATETIME to be TIMESTAMP, then you must use triggers.

Comment: This answer is not right. '0000-00-00 00:00:00' in single quotes is the "zero" equivalent for a non-null datetime field and should be avoided if possible for myriad reasons. Use a trigger to update a datetime to NOW() automatically if you really don't want to use a timestamp.

Comment: This solution will have some apis crazy with "OMG its a ZERO date! What an HERESY! We can't convert 'this' to a java.lang.Date/System.DateTime! OMG! -crashes-".

Comment: Like @CodeReaper said, it depends on what you're trying to do. I wanted it to be set to "0000-00-00 00:00:00", so this works perfectly for me and I'm upvoting it.

Comment: Zero date is not current time! ;P

Comment: If I remember correctly, this answers the second sub-question.

Answer (score 11):

On versions mysql 5.6.5 and newer, you can use precise datetimes and set default values as well.  There is a subtle bit though, which is to pass in the precision value to both the datetime and the NOW() function call.

This Example Works:

```
    ALTER TABLE my_table MODIFY created datetime(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(6);
```

This Example Does not Work:

```
    ALTER TABLE my_table MODIFY created datetime(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW();
```

Answer (score 3):

mysql 5.6 docs say that CURRENT_TIMESTAMP can be used as default for both TIMESTAMP and DATETIME data types:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Comment: Exactly from 5.6.5 because I have 5.6.22 and it does not work event if it's 5.6.. Too bad.

Answer (score 1):

```
`ALTER TABLE  `table_name` CHANGE `column_name` 
    timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
    ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Can be used to update the timestamp on update.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is using "DEFAULT 0".
Other way:

```sql
    /************ ROLE ************/
    drop table if exists `role`;
    create table `role` (
        `id_role` bigint(20) unsigned not null auto_increment,
        `date_created` datetime,
        `date_deleted` datetime,
        `name` varchar(35) not null,
        `description` text,
        primary key (`id_role`)
    ) comment='';

    drop trigger if exists `role_date_created`;
    create trigger `role_date_created` before insert
        on `role`
        for each row 
        set new.`date_created` = now();
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, using MySQL:

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` MODIFY `column_name` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
  CHANGE COLUMN date_column_name date_column_name DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Finally, This worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dateCreated` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `dateUpdated` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `mobile_UNIQUE` (`mobile`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is still active but here goes.

Regarding setting the defaults to Now(), I don't see that to be possible for the DATETIME data type. If you want to use that data type, set the date when you perform the insert like this:

```
INSERT INTO Yourtable (Field1, YourDateField) VALUES('val1', (select now()))
```

My version of mySQL is 5.5

Comment: Can be simplified as: `INSERT INTO Yourtable (Field1, YourDateField) VALUES('val1', NOW())`

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me - just changed INSERT to UPDATE for my table.

```
INSERT INTO Yourtable (Field1, YourDateField) VALUES('val1', (select now()))
```