# How to automatically update date/time in mysql database?

Tags: java, mysql

I am planning to create a attendance system in java mysql and am stuck in the date and time function. My question is how can i insert the date automatically to my database. My table looks like this:

```
  Create table automatic
(
   `id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `name` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
   `class` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `remark` varchar(255) NOT NULL,//remarks suggest presnt or absent
   `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)    
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: What date do you want? And what do you mean by 'automatically'?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818423/set-now-as-default-value-for-datetime-datatype

Comment: I am planning to create rfid based attendance system which stores the attendance of the students.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you want to insert the datetime automatically when you insert a record to DB. Use `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

```
Create table automatic
(
   `id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `name` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
   `class` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `remark` varchar(255) NOT NULL,//remarks suggest presnt or absent
   `date` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)    
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: sir hope I don't cause you any trouble can you please help me providing some example for insert function aswell!!!!

Answer (score 0):

**CURDATE()** returns the current date.

You can use it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
OrderId int NOT NULL,
ProductName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
OrderDate datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURDATE(),
PRIMARY KEY (OrderId)
)
```

Many shopping sites use this if the want to track the ti me of the order by customer.
Similarly it has tonnes of other uses.

[get more details here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_curdate.asp)

```
CREATE TABLE dates
(
    id int NOT NULL,
    id_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
INSERT INTO dates (id) VALUES (1);
SELECT id, DATE(id_date) AS id_date FROM dates;

id  id_date
1   2010-09-12
```

Comment: it displays synatx error nea CURDATE() what can I do to solve this?

Comment: I apologize,as You can't use CURDATE() as a default value.Instead you can use a TIMESTAMP column with DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. Then you will have to ignore the time part of it.