# How to create date fields on the fly using symfony/doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have a user database, and when a new user signs up, I store the name, age, address ... but there is a field in my databases named `created_at` which should store the time when the user is registerd. In plain php I used to do it like:

```
INSERT INTO users (name, created) VALUES (?, NOW())
```

But with symfony doctrine does everything and I don't know how to alter the entity or database to create the date using something equivallent to `NOW()`

Comment: You can set a default value to the field of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and it will just set the value automatically. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818423/set-now-as-default-value-for-datetime-datatype

Answer (score 1):

Add it into the constructor for the class:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->created = new \DateTime;
}
```