# Null value in column "created_at" violates not-null constraint when using upsert

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upsert, strong-parameters

Why is `created_at` null and how would I resolve this?

```
 ↳ app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:28:in `create'
  Tag Upsert (5.6ms)  INSERT INTO "tags" ("category","name") VALUES ('topic', 'career') ON CONFLICT ("id") DO UPDATE SET "type"=excluded."type","name"=excluded."name" RETURNING "id"
  ↳ app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:32:in `block in create'
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 62ms (ActiveRecord: 31.0ms | Allocations: 22999)



ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation (PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "created_at" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (5, topic, career, null, null).
):

app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:32:in `block in create'
app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:31:in `each'
app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:31:in `create'
```

```rb
# projects_controller.rb
def create
    @project = Project.create(project_params)
    if @project.valid?
      # tags
      params[:tags].each do |tag|
        @tag = Tag.upsert({ category: 'topic', name: tag })
        ProjectTag.create(tag: @tag, project: @project)
      end
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render json: { "message": "success!", status: :ok } }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`upsert`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html#method-i-upsert) works in straight SQL with very little ActiveRecord involvement:

> Updates or inserts (upserts) a single record into the database in a single SQL INSERT statement. It does not instantiate any models nor does it trigger Active Record callbacks or validations.

so AR won't touch `updated_at` or `created_at` like it usually does.

The easiest thing to do would be add a migration to add defaults in the database for `created_at` and `updated_at`:

```
change_column_default :tags, :created_at, from: nil, to: ->{ 'now()' }
change_column_default :tags, :updated_at, from: nil, to: ->{ 'now()' }
```

or you could use `current_timestamp` as the default (which will work with both PostgreSQL and MySQL):

```
change_column_default :tags, :created_at, from: nil, to: ->{ 'current_timestamp' }
change_column_default :tags, :updated_at, from: nil, to: ->{ 'current_timestamp' }
```

Then the database will take care of those columns.

Two things to note in the migration:

1. Passing the `:from` and `:to` options instead of just the new default gives you a reversible migration.
2. You have to use a lambda for the `:to` value so that the PostgreSQL `now()` function will be used rather than the string `'now()'`. Similarly if you use `current_timestamp` instead of `now()`.

Comment: Thank you! I somehow fail to understand upsert's functionality. Shouldn't it update columns that were previously set to `nil`?

Somehow I ended up with a new error after migrating: `NoMethodError (undefined method 'keys' for [:category, "topic"]:Array)` (for the upsert)

Comment: Upserts are done in straight SQL using the SQL you see in the log, AR does very little so you have to arrange everything, all your `created_at` and `updated_at` columns should have defaults in the database anyway (IMO).  You've changed your code from `Tag.upsert` to `Tag.upsert_all`, right?

Comment: Changed it back, didn't help anything. I feel super out of my depth here and aren't sure where to even start looking. I assume it's best to open a new thread from here on out. Thanks again.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a DB-specific solution, so MySQL would have to use [something different](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5818452/41688), ditto for Sqlite, etc.

Comment: @BryanH `->{ 'current_timestamp' }` as a default should work for both PostgreSQL and MySQL, not sure about SQLite though.