# SQL WHERE on now() not working correctly?

Tags: mysql

I have the following query....

```
SELECT fixture_date FROM tbl_foot_games WHERE fixture_date < now() AND leagueid = '68' AND (type = '2' OR type = '12' OR type = '22' OR type = '32') GROUP BY fixture_date ORDER BY fixture_date
```

This is outputting the following....

> 1318876658
>   1319135858
>   1319395058
>   1319654258
>   1319913458
>   1320176258
>   1320435458
>   1320694658
>   1320953858
>   1321213058
>   1321472258

All of these timestamps are ahead of right now. 
Any idea why it is outputting anything?

I do however, need to change the now() to 3 days in the future. 72 hours!

Any ideas?
Thanks :)

Comment: just a minor enhancement you could also do, AND type IN ('2', '12', '22', '32')

Comment: I'll amend @bumperbox 's comment to say you _should_ get in the habit of using `IN ()`, as it saves you debugging when you've forgotten to surround the `OR` groups in `()` and you start getting all sorts of unwanted rows.

Comment: Ok guys, thanks for the advice...had never heard of this before and as you say Michael, debugging for it is a pain!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT fixture_date 
FROM tbl_foot_games 
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(fixture_date) < NOW() 
  AND leagueid = '68' 
AND type IN ('2', '12', '22', '32') 
GROUP BY fixture_date 
ORDER BY fixture_date
```

But you should really not store timestamps as `CHAR` or `VARCHAR`.

Comment: Yes! That works perfectly, was just searching google for a way to convert the timestamp! Very very much appreciate this :) Cheers bud...

Comment: And this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989539/when-to-use-datetime-or-timestamp

Comment: For the differences `timestamp` vs. `datetime` and what to use.

Answer (score 1):

change your query to:

```
SELECT NOW(), fixture_date FROM tbl_foot_games ...
```

to see what `NOW()` returns. your query seems to be correct (the `GROUP BY` looks a bit senseless to me...). to ask for a future date, use [date_add](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) like this:

```
... WHERE fixture_date < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) ...
```

Comment: @Luke If you need to group repeating rows, only `ORDER BY` is needed. `GROUP BY` is for aggregates like `COUNT(), SUM(), AVG()`, etc.

Comment: yes good idea. check what NOW() is by selecting it. there could be different time zones then you expect

Comment: I have several rows with the same fixture_date so I group them? If i remove the group by, I end up with them all displaying individually? And this still isn't working. Those are the timestamps above and even when i go three days in the future, i'm still getting them all display???

Comment: @bumperbox - it's showing timestamps till november, the zones couldnt be that far out??

Comment: When I echo now(), i get 2011-10-14 21:49:23....how does that compare to a timestamp? Is that the problem?

Comment: is the mysql column a timestamp type or a datetime time?

Comment: Oooops it's storing a timestamp but it's of varchar type...is there anything i can do about that?

Comment: instead of NOW(), try UNIX_TIMESTAMP() for comparison. i haven't tried it, but see if that make a difference. mysql timestamps are not the same as unix timestamps

Comment: Don't think that has worked! It's just made everything disappear.