# ConcurrencyCheck/Datatype

Tags: breeze

In breeze.debug.js:

```
function updateConcurrencyProperty(entity, property) {

...

else if (property.datatype === DataType.Binary) {
            // best guess - that this is a timestamp column and is computed on the server during save 
            // - so no need to set it here.
            return;
        } else {
            // this just leaves DataTypes of Boolean, String and Byte - none of which should be the
            // type for a concurrency column.
            // NOTE: thought about just returning here but would rather be safe for now. 
            throw new Error("Unable to update the value of concurrency property before saving: " + property.name);
        }
```

i have a timestamp on my models. Why is this not recommended? An EF Tutorial on ASP.Net uses the timestamp. 
What would you recommend as Concurrencycheck column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where we say it's not recommended; the only issue is that its not terribly portable across databases,  SQLServer 'timestamp' columns are not actually time based, ... but they should still work as concurrency columns with breeze.  If not, its likely a bug.

For more info: [datetime or timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989539/when-to-use-datetime-or-timestamp)

Comment: In the comment above:
    
(// this just leaves DataTypes of Boolean, String and Byte - none of which should be the
            // type for a concurrency column.)

Comment: Timestamp is of DataTime.Binary. ( not byte).

Comment: I'm with Jay on this. Timestamp is fine but DateTime isn't granular enough to be a concurrency column. Int and Double are good choices too.

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug involving SQL Server Timestamp columns that is now fixed in v 0.76.4.  ... Thanks for finding this, Sascha.