# Comparing two time columns in ASP.NET

Tags: t-sql

I'm rather new to ASP.NET and SQL, so I'm having a tough time trying to figure out how to compare two time columns.  I have a timestamped column and then a Now() column in an .mdb database.  I need to have a gridview display records that are "Greater than or equal to 3 hours" from the timestamp. Any idea how I can accomplish this?

Comment: When to use datetime or timestamp is [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989539/when-to-use-datetime-or-timestamp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Transact-SQL timestamp data type is a binary data type with no time-related values.

So to answer your question: Is there a way to get DateTime value from timestamp type column?

The answer is: No

You need another column of `datetime2` type and use `>` operator to for comparison. You might want to set default value of `getutcdate()` to set it when each row is inserted.

UPDATE:

Since the column is of `datetime` type and not `timestamp` type (there is a type in SQL Server called `timestamp`, hence the confusion) you can just do

`WHERE [TimeCalled] <= DATEADD(hour, -3, GETDATE())`

Make sure your server is running in the same timezone as your code. It may be safer to store all dates in UTC. In that case use `GETUTCDATE` instead on `GETDATE`

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I am not sure I understand your reply, though. Let me better explain what I have going on.  I have an .mdb file and I need to compare one column that got timestamped with a Now() function. I am entering records in the database and I use the Now() function to timestamp a "TimeCalled" column for when I enter that record. I then need to display in a gridview or listview all records that are 3 hours or older. This column is a "Date/Time" datatype. How would I go about writing an SQL statement for SELECTING those records that are 3 hours older or greater?

Comment: Thank you again for your quick reply! I will give this a shot right now! I wasn't sure how exactly to use the DATEADD function. Sorry again for the confusion!

Comment: Changed `>=` to `<=` as I thought that you want records within last 3 hours.

Comment: When I try to execute that query in Visual Studio 2010, I am getting the following error: Error Source: Microsoft Jet Database Engine, Error Message: Undefined function "GETDATE" in expression.

Comment: Oh, you're using Access, sorry. You will need to pass it as a parameter. Just pass the value of `Now()`

Comment: Ok, when doing that, I receive the following error: No value given for one or more required parameters.  My query looks like this: SELECT ReferenceID, FirstName, LastName FROM customers WHERE (TimeCalled <= DATEADD([hour], - 3, NOW()))

Comment: No, you need to pass current datetime as a parameter to your SQL query. Read about parametrized queries. Or render the actual datetime in the query - `DATEADD([hour], - 3, '2012-12-13 13:23:22'))`

Comment: When trying to use the actual time in the query I still get the error about no value being given. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. What does the "Hour" parameter do in that query?

Comment: Would using:

SELECT ReferenceID, FirstName, LastName FROM customers WHERE (DATEDIFF([hour], TimeCalled, NOW()) >= 3)

be a valid statement? By the way, I am typing this in the Query Builder part of Visual Studio. When I execute that query I still get an error saying that there is no vaule give for one or more require parameters.

Comment: Ok, after messing with it for a while, I finally got it to work using your statement, BUT I had to change "hour" to "'h'".  It wasn't understanding what "hour" was. Thank you very much for your help and for excusing my ignorance!

Answer (score 0):

Timestamps are generally used to track changes to records, and are updated every time the record is changed. If you want to store a specific value you should use a datetime field.

If you're using a DateTime Column and you want the result in TSQL try

```
DATEDIFF(Hour, 'Your DateTime Column here', 'pass Now() here' )
```

try to execute this example in TSQL:

```
select DATEDIFF(Hour, '2012-11-10 00:00:59.900', '2012-11-10 05:01:00.100')
```

Comment: When to use datetime or timestamp is [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989539/when-to-use-datetime-or-timestamp)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, yes, I think I misused the term "timestamp".  I was using it as a general term, not the actual timestamp function. I was using the Now() function when inserting a record. Therefore, it just catches the time that record was inserted, the problem is that I now need to check the table for records that are older than 3 hours.

Comment: If you're using a DateTime Column and you want the result in TSQL try `DATEDIFF(Hour, 'Your DateTime Column here', 'pass Now() here' )`

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2010 and am working with asp.net. So I am trying to fill a gridview with records that are older than 3 hours. How would I do that using a SELECT statement? I'm not a very advanced programmer, so step by step instructions would be great, thank you!