# Date gets overwritten (Spring/Hibernate)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, date, spring-mvc

Right now I have a "bookings" table on my main page which shows information about different bookings. One of the fields is "Booking Date" which shows the date and time of the creation of the booking. But when I edit the booking it automatically gets overwritten by a new date. How do I keep that from happening?

My Booking class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="booking")
public class Booking {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="R_id")
    private Restaurant restaurant;

    @Column(name="date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date date;

    @Column(name="start")
    private String start;

    @Column(name="duration")
    private float duration;

    @Column(name="amount_of_people")
    private int amountOfPeople;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="contact_preference")
    private String contactPreference;

    @Column(name="phone_number")
    private String phoneNumber;

    @Column(name="comments")
    private String comments;

    // Date that gets overwritten
    @Column(name="current_datetime")
    @Type(type="timestamp")
    private Date currentDatetime;

    @Column(name="new_date")
    @Type(type="timestamp")
    private Date newDate;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Restaurant getRestaurant() {
        return restaurant;
    }

    public void setRestaurant(Restaurant restaurant) {
        this.restaurant = restaurant;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getStart() {
        return start;
    }

    public void setStart(String start) { this.start = start; }

    public float getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(float duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public int getAmountOfPeople() {
        return amountOfPeople;
    }

    public void setAmountOfPeople(int amountOfPeople) {
        this.amountOfPeople = amountOfPeople;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getContactPreference() {
        return contactPreference;
    }

    public void setContactPreference(String contactPreference) {
        this.contactPreference = contactPreference;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() { return phoneNumber; }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) { this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber; }

    public String getComments() {
        return comments;
    }

    public void setComments(String comments) {
        this.comments = comments;
    }

    public Date getCurrentDatetime() {
        return currentDatetime;
    }

    public void setCurrentDatetime(Date currentDatetime) { this.currentDatetime = currentDatetime; }

    public Date getNewDate() { return newDate; }

    public void setNewDate(Date newDate) { this.newDate = newDate; }

    // Comparator
    public static class BookingDateComparator implements Comparator<Booking> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Booking booking1, Booking booking2) {
            if (booking1.getDate().compareTo(booking2.getDate()) == 0) {
                return booking1.getStart().compareTo(booking2.getStart());
            }
            return booking1.getDate().compareTo(booking2.getDate());
        }
    }

}
```

Relevant methods in my MainController class:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "bookings", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String bookings(Model model) {
    List<Booking> bookingList = bookingService.getBookings();
    model.addAttribute("bookings", bookingList);
    initModelList(model);
    return "bookings";
}
    @RequestMapping(value = "booking/create", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String createBooking(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("booking", new Booking());
    initModelList(model);
    return "newBooking";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "booking/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createBookingAction(@Valid @ModelAttribute ("booking") Booking booking, BindingResult result, Model model) {
    BookingFormValidator bookingFormValidator = new BookingFormValidator();
    bookingFormValidator.validate(booking, result);
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        initModelList(model);
        return "newBooking";
    }
    bookingService.addBooking(booking);
    return "redirect:/bookings";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "booking/edit/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String editBooking(@PathVariable Long id, Model model) {
    initModelList(model);
    Booking booking = bookingService.getBooking(id);
    model.addAttribute("booking", booking);
    return "editBooking";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "booking/edit/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String editBookingAction(@Valid @ModelAttribute ("booking") Booking booking, BindingResult result, Model model) {
    BookingFormValidator bookingFormValidator = new BookingFormValidator();
    bookingFormValidator.validate(booking, result);
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        initModelList(model);
        return "editBooking";
    }
    bookingService.updateBooking(booking);
    return "redirect:/bookings";
}
```

The .jsp of my main page

```
<body>
<jsp:include page="../fragments/menu.jsp"/>
<div id="body">

    <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">


        <h2>List of bookings</h2>

        <p>
            <a href="/restaurant/create">Add restaurant</a>
            <a href="/booking/create">Create New Booking</a>
        </p>
        <table class="">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Booking information
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>

            <c:forEach items="${restaurants}" var="restaurants">
                <tr>
                    <td><h3>${restaurants}</h3></td>
                    <td valign="bottom"><a href="/restaurant/edit/${restaurants.id}">Edit restaurant</a></td>

                    <tr>
                        <table>
                            <col align="left" width="100">
                            <col align="left" width="60">
                            <col align="left" width="60">
                            <col align="left" width="60">
                            <col align="left" width="60">
                            <col align="left" width="90">
                            <col align="left" width="90">
                            <col align="left" width="90">
                            <col align="left" width="100">
                            <col align="left" width="100">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="left"><b>Date</b></td>
                                <td align="left"><b>Start</b></td>
                                <td align="left"><b>Duration</b></td>
                                <td align="left"><b># Of People</b></td>
                                <td align="left"><b>Name</b></td>
                                <td align="left"><b>Contact Pref.</b></td>
                                <td align="left"><b>Phone #</b></td>
                                <td align="left"><b>Comments</b></td>
                                <td align="left"><b>Booking date</b></td>
                            </tr>
                            <c:forEach items="${sortedBooking}" var="sortedBooking">
                                <c:choose>
                                    <c:when test="${restaurants == sortedBooking.restaurant.restaurantName}">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>${sortedBooking.date}</td>
                                            <td>${sortedBooking.start}</td>
                                            <td>${sortedBooking.duration}</td>
                                            <td>${sortedBooking.amountOfPeople}</td>
                                            <td>${sortedBooking.name}</td>
                                            <td>${sortedBooking.contactPreference}</td>
                                            <c:choose>
                                                <c:when test="${sortedBooking.phoneNumber.equals('')}">
                                                    <td>NO PHONE</td>
                                                </c:when>
                                                <c:otherwise>
                                                    <td>${sortedBooking.phoneNumber}</td>
                                                </c:otherwise>
                                            </c:choose>
                                            <c:choose>
                                                <c:when test="${sortedBooking.comments.equals('')}">
                                                    <td>NO COMMENTS</td>
                                                </c:when>
                                                <c:otherwise>
                                                    <td>${sortedBooking.comments}</td>
                                                </c:otherwise>
                                            </c:choose>
                                            <td>${sortedBooking.currentDatetime}</td>
                                            <td><a href="/booking/edit/${sortedBooking.id}">Edit booking</a></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </c:when>
                                </c:choose>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </table>
                    </tr>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>

    </section>
</div>
<jsp:include page="../fragments/footer.jsp"/>

</body>
```

My editBooking.jsp:

```
<body>
<jsp:include page="../fragments/menu.jsp"/>
<div id="body">
    <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">

        <h2>Edit</h2>

        <form:form modelAttribute="booking">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Restaurant*:</td>
                    <td><form:select path="restaurant.id">
                            <form:option value="" label="--- Select ---" />
                            <form:options items="${restaurants}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="restaurantName" />
                    <td><form:errors path="restaurant.id" cssClass="error"/></td>
                    </form:select>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Date*:</td>
                    <td><form:input path="date" type="date"/></td>
                    <td><form:errors path="date" cssClass="error"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Starting time*:</td>
                    <td><form:input path="start" type="time"/></td>
                    <td><form:errors path="start" cssClass="error"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Duration*:</td>
                    <td><form:input path="duration"/></td>
                    <td><form:errors path="duration" cssClass="error"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Amount of people*:</td>
                    <td><form:input path="amountOfPeople"/></td>
                    <td><form:errors path="amountOfPeople" cssClass="error"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name*:</td>
                    <td><form:input path="name"/></td>
                    <td><form:errors path="name" cssClass="error"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Contact preference*:</td>
                    <td><form:select path="contactPreference">
                            <form:option value="" label="--- Select ---" />
                            <form:option value="e-mail" label="E-mail" />
                            <form:option value="phone" label="Phone" />
                            <form:option value="other" label="Other" />
                    <td><form:errors path="contactPreference" cssClass="error"/></td>
                    </form:select>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Phone number:</td>
                    <td><form:input path="phoneNumber"/></td>
                    <td><form:errors path="phoneNumber" cssClass="error"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Comments:</td>
                    <td><form:textarea path="comments" rows="5" cols="30"/></td>
                    <td><form:errors path="comments" cssClass="error"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form:form>
        <div>
            <a href="/bookings">Back to List</a>
        </div>


    </section>
</div>
<jsp:include page="../fragments/footer.jsp"/>

</body>
```

Any help is appreciated! Sorry for the long post.

EDIT: I tried changin my code to disable updating, but it still doesn't work.

```
@Column(name="current_datetime", updatable=false, nullable=false)
@Type(type="timestamp")
private Date currentDatetime = new Date();
```

Comment: what does you `editBookingAction` do? does it SaveOrUpdate? are you sure that its not creating new record? can you try annotating your date with `@CreationTimestamp`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `@Type(type="timestamp")` for storing dates. In many databases timestamps are intended to track changes instead of being an ordinary date field for your application logic. So, switch to DATETIME in the database and remove the `@Type` annotation, as hibernate already converts `Date` to the proper type.

**See also:**

- [Should I use field 'datetime' or 'timestamp'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/should-i-use-field-datetime-or-timestamp)
- [When to use datetime or timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989539/when-to-use-datetime-or-timestamp)