# what type of data use in mysql to save data time

Tags: mysql, html

I create an html form and I used HTML5 `datatype` field to insert data.what type of mysql attribute I could use to save the datatime in a db?

```
<input type="datetime" name="dt" id="dt" value="" placeholder="Date"/>
```

Comment: You'll need to convert it to a format that the `DATETIME` column type understands.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+data+type+for+time Many many related questions....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql date field, why so many options?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6378444/mysql-date-field-why-so-many-options)

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562888/which-is-the-better-way-of-storing-date-and-time-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to use the `DATETIME` data type.
**[Have a loot at the Manual.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html)**