# Selecting all timestamps for a certain date in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with a few records and for each of these records I've also added a UNIX_TIMESTAMP. Now, I also have a search engine for those records in which I can choose a date using a jQuery datapicker. My question is how do I make the request so that to select all timestamps from the database for a certain date.

Comment: `SELECT column(s) FROM table WHERE date='?'`

Comment: You read a few SQL tutorials, and then try to get it to work by trial and error. Or that was how we learnt stuff back in the olden days, at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With an index on your timestamp column you will get a faster result with:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table_name
 WHERE time_stamp_column_name >= :date_picked
   AND time_stamp_column_name <  :date_picked + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Where `:date_picked` is your bound-in picked date as a string in the format `'YYYY-MM-DD'`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`from_unixtime`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) to convert it into a date

```
select *
from 
  table
where
date(from_unixtime(your_timestamp_col)) = '2014-10-01'
```

Comment: You could, but you'd render any index useless.

Answer (score 0):

use [unix timestamp](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)
you can also [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7029127/using-mysqls-timestamp-vs-storing-timestamps-directly)