# mySQL time stamp to an integer?

Tags: php, mysql

Hi there Stack Overflow community, I'm new to stack overflow so excuse me if I happen to make any mistakes etc.

Anyway, my question is that I have a time stamp on a MySQL database cell (and the column is set to a time stamp format), with a date of 2015-06-01 12:55:24 (with that format), and I wanted to convert it into an integer in my PHP code.

I've read that Strtotime() can be implemented into it to make that happen, but since I'm a newbie to PHP, I wouldn't be too sure as to how that can be done? If Strtotime() isn't the correct function / process, then what would be?

Cheers to any possible solutions,
Kindest regards,

Joshua

Comment: see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7029127/using-mysqls-timestamp-vs-storing-timestamps-directly. It points out that you can get the column returned as an int using MySQL's built-in function: `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(<the column name goes here>)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

To convert a date/time to a Unix timestamp, the [`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function should work just fine.

You can pass many types of date/time strings to this function, however, for your use here is an example:

```
$datetime = "2015-06-01 12:55:24";
$timestamp = strtotime($datetime); //1433177724
```

#### Unix Timestamp?

Simply put, the [Unix Timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) is the number of seconds since the January 1, 1970 at 00:00:00 UTC. Many web programs use this timestamp to parse dates and times.

Comment: Hi there, First of all thank you for your reply, and second of all, it works perfectly! Thanks for the help :)