# Store an already UTC timestamp in TIMESTAMP field without further conversion in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, utc

As per the MySQL documentation:

> MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval.

I am ok with the conversion for the retrieval but for storage I already have an UTC timestamp. It is sent like this from the client as it is a value calculated on the client side and I want to avoid time zone conversions (because I think this will add complexity to the client-server communication).

How can I insert this value avoiding further conversion?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want MySQL to do any conversions, maybe the simplest way is to just store the timestamp in a numeric field.
This might be bad practice depending on what you are going to do with it, this thread has some discussion on the pros and cons:
[Using MySQL's TIMESTAMP vs storing timestamps directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7029127/using-mysqls-timestamp-vs-storing-timestamps-directly)

Comment: Thanks @glaux, I still want the conversion on retrieval. As the timestamp is computed in the client side I thought that it will be simpler to just send the timestamp in UTC to avoid dealing with client timezone vs server timezone issues. But again I am still interested in the conversion at retrieval, so I will go on with the TIMESTAMP field type.

Answer (score 0):

For now I am using this workaround:

```
CONVERT_TZ('2009-06-15T13:45:30.0000000Z','+00:00','SYSTEM')
```

I would prefer no to convert a value that will be converted again (although internally) but it seems to be the more convenient solution for me.

Another option is to use:

```
SET time_zone = '+00:00';
--- your query here
SET time_zone = 'SYSTEM';
```

But in my case as I only needed to convert only two fields and that seemed like overkill although in this case there should be no conversion at all.