# Convert String to Date mysql

Tags: java, mysql, date

I need to convert a string to date to allow me insert information in mysql table:

I tried this:

```
System.out.println("Escribe la fecha de nacimiento de socio:");
//Traduction to english:        set the date of birthday //

String fechaSocio  = sc.next();

Date fecha = null;
try {
  fecha = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy").parse(fechaSocio);
} catch (ParseException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

but It's converting like that: `Thu Mar 21 00:00:00 CET 1996`

I need to convert to this :

01-01-1987
or 01011987

```
public class SocioDao {
static ClaseConexion conexion = new ClaseConexion();
```

public void insertar(Socio misocio){

```
System.out.println(misocio.getDATA_NAIXEMENT());
System.out.println("..........................");


  try {

        Statement statuo = conexion.getConnection().createStatement();


        statuo.executeUpdate("insert into socis(CODI_SOCI,DNI,NOM,COGNOMS,"
                + "DATA_NAIXEMENT,ADRECA,POBLACIO,TELEFON) values ('"
                + misocio.getCODI_SOCI() + "','" + misocio.getDNI()
                + "',' " + misocio.getNOM() + "','" + misocio.getCOGNOMS()
                + "','" + misocio.getDATA_NAIXEMENT() + "','"
                + misocio.getADREÇA() + "','" + misocio.getPOBLACIO()
                + "','" + misocio.getTELEFON() + "')");

        statuo.close();
        conexion.desconectar();
        System.out.println("Socio añadido correctamente");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("No se puede añadir un nuevo socio");




    }

}
```

}

Comment: You've only shown us the parsing. You haven't shown us how you try to set the date in the MySQL query.

Comment: Where are getting `Thu Mar 21 00:00:00 CET 1996` from?

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you are trying to pass a `Date` as a `String` in your MySQL query.

Don't. Instead use the appropriate date setter method in the [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) class.

Remember, **a `Date` doesn't have a format.** A format is only for displaying a date.

Comment: See [this other answer by BalusC](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7626080/642706) for an example of what this answer suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql function if you are trying to insert date in database..

for example:

```
INSERT INTO test (sampledate) VALUES (CURDATE());
```