# PreparedStatement and CURDATE() MySQL function

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

What is the correct way to use CURDATE() mysql function in PreparedStatements?
Table column is DATE type and inserted value in table must be like 1988-07-29.

```
ps.setDate(5, ...);
```

Comment: (http://stackoverflow.com/a/7626080/2749470) this may help you out

Comment: Why not make the `curdate()` call part of your SQL statement and remove the parameter for it?

Comment: @BhargavModi should accept your answer as accepted, it works

Comment: way let me add it as a answer should I if it helped you??

Comment: @BhargavModi I think Yes, because the answer is just use now() in SQL statement and remove the parameter for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in two ways one is from `java` as below 
Using java.sql.Date

e.g.:
Using `java.sql.Date`:

```
java.sql.Date date = java.sql.Date.valueOf("2013-09-04");
```

If you want to insert the current date:

```
ps.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

Using `java.sql.Timestamp`:

```
ps.setTimestamp(2, new java.sql.Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

Another way is from `SQL` through database support operations like `now()` for `MySQL` or `current_timestamp()` for `PostgreSQL` etc just have a look on below example

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO user (email, creationdate) VALUES (?, now())";//for MySQL
```

for more details [Use this link](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/how-to-insert-date-value-in-preparedstatement/)(one of my favourite author).

Happy to Help you :)

Answer (score 2):

There is none. You either create current date in Java or prepare the statement with CURDATE()

Answer (score 2):

Do Like:

```
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String fd = f.format(new Date());
Date date = f.parse(fd);
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(index, new Timestamp(date.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Do Like

```
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(5, new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
```