# Please explain how to use date in a prepared statement for a Select

Tags: java, prepared-statement

Yes, there are alot of post on this topic, but all of them seem to be in regards to inserting data. I am in need of pulling data.

I just found what the problem is but I have not found out how to write it out correctly. have a prepared statement that I found in one of our projects that does not work.

I have traced it down to where we are checking if a date is >= x AND <= Y.

I have been on this problem literally all day.

```
statement.append("SELECT error_code FROM dw.transaction_error_logs");
statement.append(" WHERE activity_timestamp >= '?'");
statement.append(" AND activity_timestamp <= '?'");
```

The DB is Postgres and the column is type 'timestamp with time'.
I have tried it without the quotes but then I get errors with the characters being passed as the values are like '2015-11-12 17:37:45'

Comment: `statement.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(...));`? (I think some JDBC drivers might allow a `java.util.Date`, but you'd need to check that against your drivers documentation)

Comment: Oh, and you won't need to quote the marks (`'?'`), then can just be `?`

Comment: You don't write the parameters as String in where clause. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7626076/how-to-set-current-date-and-time-using-prepared-statement) as an example

Comment: I really don't care about the -1 vote. I have spent hours looking but not knowing what to look for makes it hard to find answers. It was all from some old projects I had dumped on me this week.

Comment: Thank you very much MadProgrammer I just figured with all of those Insert questions people were asking that it would be different as I am pulling data.

Comment: I pretty sure I do this with select statements all the time.  Maybe have a look at [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: Put your answer from above as an answer so I can tag it as the answer. Thank you for putting me on the right path.