# Call a function from a field in Java PreparedStatement?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

Having a PreparedStament, I have a field of type timestamp and I don't want to set it to a fixed value but call NOW() instead. How do I do that?

I tried:

```
statement.setString(11, "NOW()")
```

but that tries to set the field to the string "NOW()" instead of calling NOW().

Thanks.

Comment: Could you share the query code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7626076/how-to-set-current-date-and-time-using-prepared-statement

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do that.  But in the SQL of the prepared statement, instead of using `?`, you can use `NOW()`.

Alternatively, you can keep the `?` in the SQL, and do `statement.setDate( 11, new Date() );`

Answer (score 1):

Call `preparedStatement.setTimeStamp(11, LocalDateTime.now().toString())`

If you aren't using Java 8, or want to learn how to get the current time as a String, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175728/how-to-get-the-current-date-time-in-java).

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are willing to call `mysql now()` function that returns the current date-time stamp.

If so, then you must put `now()` in `queryString` as "String part of the query", if you try to put it using `preparedStatement` then it will be treated as *pure string value* not as *`mysql` function.*...  see this
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-now/

- OR

If you want to call a java code function named `now()` then remove the double quotes from it and make sure it `returns String`.