# Which is the correct datatype to store time in SQL?

Tags: mysql, time

Here's my table right now (using mysql):

```
SQL Table: koko_table
  name varchar(140)
  status varchar(140)
  time TIMESTAMP
```

My issue basically is , I have a form (using php) which user uses to store data only in the status column, my time column captures the time as a permanent data when the user stores in the status column. I think I have not been using accurate DATATYPE for time column, because everytime I visit my database, the time column has different values.

What can be the correct datatype to store time of status input by the user as  un-changeable data.

Comment: If the value keeps changing without you explicitly saving new values, the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: actually my php code saves only the status and the name into the database, leaving the TIMESTAMP column to store time on its own.. Am I doing it right? or should I use a NOW() function to explicitly store time in the TIMESTAMP column?

Comment: A column doesn't automatically update itself unless it has `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: @Juhana: The default behaviour for the first timestamp of a table is exactly this: `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/datetime-vs-timestamp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best data type would be DATETIME.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either `TIMESTAMP` or `DATETIME` in MySQL to store date and time.

There are differences though:

- `TIMESTAMP` uses 4 bytes, `DATETIME` 8 bytes.
- Timestamps can be between `1970`  and `2038`, while datetimes can be between `1000-01-01 00:00:00` and `9999-12-32 23:59:59`.
- `TIMESTAMP` values are converted from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and converted back from UTC to the (server's) current time zone for retrieval. This does not happen for `DATETIME` values where no timezone is implied.
- `Datetime` fields have to be declared in `INSERT` operations while `timestamp` fields have the special feature that the first timestamp of a table is (by default) automatically inserted or updated at every `INSERT` or `UPDATE` operation with the current timestamp. (That's probably what you are seeing in your scenario.) You can change this behaviour, so only Inserts or only Updates set the timestamp to current timestamp. See **[MySQL docs: Timestamp properties](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/timestamp.html)**

To have for example the timestamp automatically stored at Inserts but not changed during Updates, you could set:

```
ALTER TABLE TableName
  CHANGE TimeStampName TimeStampName TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ;
```

Comment: Will there be a problem while updating a single column in a table with DATETIME being there in the table? does the DATETIME also need to be updated?

Comment: the default has been set to DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP but it still changes? what might be?

Comment: @jenny: Please add in your question the definition of the whole table.

Comment: ok I get it...I should not have used TIMESTAMP.. DATETIME is flexible for what I am asking.

Comment: Actually the default was already set to CURRENT TIMESTAMP, anyways my app works better for datetime datatype..thanks yper

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefered DATETIME (the long number) or store it as a formated string like 2011/10/18 13:50. The first one is better in performance and the secound one is easyer to edit on phpMyAdmin or something like that.