# Inserting date to database in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I use NOW() function but I get this weird date:

2011-11-06

How do I get the following European date:

ss:mm:hh dd:mm:year  (06-11-2011)

In my database I set the field column date as DATE

How do you integrate DATEFORMAT into this query:

```
   $avatar_Q=mysql_query("
                SELECT user_name,avatar,reputation,comment, DATE_FORMAT(date,'%d/%m/%Y %h:%i') AS rightNow
                FROM comments AS com
                INNER JOIN users AS us ON com.user_id=us.user_id
                WHERE comment_id=$commentID
       ") or die(mysql_error());
```

The date is is in the column table

Comment: by **weird** you mean YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: Re your update - you need to include table name in the select statement - ie `users.username`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL uses the following date format - YYYY-MM-DD - if you want a different format you need to use the `DATE_FORMAT` function on select

for example :

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datecolumn,"%d/%m/%Y %h:%i")
FROM atable
```

To integrate the `date_format` function into your `select` statement you need to list the fields individually

Comment: updated my answer..it gives me this: Column 'date' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: @WithFlyingColors you mean question ? you need to include the table name in the select list - ie `users.user_name, tablename.date` etc etc ...

Comment: alright..I got what I wanted..sometimes I get this for some reason

Comment: I use this to insert time :  $date=time(); and then I insert $date to an insert statemnet

Comment: @WithFlyingColors when you select from multiple tables (ie join) you need to specify the tablename in the select statment

Comment: @WithFlyingColors you could use the sql function NOW() -> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now

Answer (score 1):

Yep, use a **Timestamp** column and insert with **CURRENT_TIMESTAMP**. It saves a lot of time! :)

Comment: Depends what your column is for - check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/datetime-vs-timestamp

Comment: Never had any kind of problem using TimeStamp type column. Also, is a lot faster that Date column since it uses UNIX Time Stamp like format. So you should use TimeStamp instead of Date. Also, with PHP you get the correct result without a single line of code!

Comment: I didnt say it was wrong to use the `TIMESTAMP` data type ... just depends on the situation - no idea what the OP is using the column for

Comment: I'm glad to help you! :)
Timestamp can also make use of date add and date diff without any issues, at least, for me. Also, since it's a integer value e more accurate and fast to perform queries with, including comparing dates. I've once seen a benchmark. I'll post it here if I see it again :)

Answer (score 0):

My personal recommendation is to save the date as a UNIX Timestamp (using the `time()` function) ,

This way you could format it as you wish .

Shai.

Comment: Depends what your column is for check this out -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/datetime-vs-timestamp

Comment: @ManseUK: Good point. There is also some tip on why not to use Unix timestamp within database and why native timestamp is better. It is a good idea not to store Unix timestamps, but use `TIMESTAMP` column type instead.

Comment: @Tadeck theres are use for both datatypes - certainly agree with that :-)

Answer (score 0):

`DATE_FORMAT`
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 0):

That format is just how MySQL stores the data type DATE: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html.

If you're using the `DATE` data type for you column you can either:

1. Use the `DATE_FORMAT` function in your SQL to get the date in your desired format
2. Use a combination of PHP's [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) functions to display your date in the most appropriate format