# Convert from SQLite to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sqlite

This table I created in a SQLite database:

```
CREATE TABLE [tickets] (
[id] INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
[coupon_id] INTEGER  NULL,
[size] FLOAT  NULL,
[phone] VARCHAR(10)  NULL,
[date] DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE NULL,
[time] TIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIME NULL,
[product] TEXT  NULL
);
```

Now `INSERT` operation is:

```
INSERT INTO "tickets" VALUES(429,9,18.16,'949-893-5032','2010-11-30','17:46:39','Kids’ Kups Berry Interesting&trade;');
INSERT INTO "tickets" VALUES(430,9,12.04,'847-188-1359','2010-11-25','10:54:00','Raspberry Collider&trade;');
INSERT INTO "tickets" VALUES(431,9,14.1,'204-682-5560','2010-12-08','15:34:07','Celestial Cherry High&trade;');
```

Now the same table I created in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE tickets (
id INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
coupon_id INTEGER  NULL,
size FLOAT  NULL,
phone VARCHAR(10)  NULL,
date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NULL,
time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NULL,
product TEXT  NULL
);
```

`INSERT` operation for MySQL is:

```
INSERT INTO tickets VALUES(429,9,18.16,'949-893-5032','2010-11-30','17:46:39','Kids’ Kups Berry Interesting&trade;');
INSERT INTO tickets VALUES(430,9,12.04,'847-188-1359','2010-11-25','10:54:00','Raspberry Collider&trade;');
INSERT INTO tickets VALUES(431,9,14.1,'204-682-5560','2010-12-08','15:34:07','Celestial Cherry High&trade;');
```

When i am inserting those values I got an error :-`there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with current_timestamp in default of on update clause`

…but I am not able to insert all those values into MySQL. Help me?

Comment: problem is only to insert the value in mysql

Comment: Right, and if you can't `INSERT` into MySQL, MySQL is without doubt giving you an error message as to why it doesn't like your `INSERT` statements. Read it, understand it, and at least post it here, so that we might help you.

Comment: Thanatos :) Question edited, I am newbie in stack overflow so don't no how to ask the questions. next time i remember

Answer (score 1):

In SQLite you have two columns

```
[date] DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE NULL,
[time] TIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIME NULL,
```

while on MySQL you have only one

```
date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NULL,
```

and you're trying to insert two values on it...

You should try

```
INSERT INTO tickets VALUES(..., '2010-11-30 17:46:39', ...)
```

Comment: Marco:)exactly the same but  if i want to insert the same as above then ?

Comment: @root: use a `DATE` column and a `TIME` column ;)

Comment: INSERT INTO tickets VALUES(429,9,18.16,'949-893-5032','2010-11-30','17:46:39','Kids’ Kups Berry Interesting&trade;');

Comment: i got an error :-there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with current_timestamp in default of on update clause

Comment: @root: I've just created a table with two fields (one `DATE` and one `TIME`) then I tried `INSERT INTO tb VALUES('2010-11-30', '17:46:39') and it worked...

Comment: ok so can you plz edit in the answer what you are doing in your codes ... after all i am trying again

Answer (score 1):

At first glace, your `varchar` column is size 10, but you are inserting greater than length 10 data into it. Make sure your `varchar` column is wide enough for your data.

Comment: +1 for noting OP's *next* problem (i.e. MySQL evil silent data truncation) after they get the right number of VALUES for the columns.

Comment: It's not entirely silent, is it? I think it at least spews a warning somewhere. (Although, personally, I'd like to have it abort in such a situation.)

Comment: Anything less than blowing up in your face and screaming bloody murder is too silent for me. You can [tighten it up](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_all_tables) though but fewer people do that than pay attention to the warning (wherever it goes).

Answer (score 0):

Your MySQL Schema appears to be incorrect for what you're trying to insert.

Excerpt from this post: [Should I use field 'datetime' or 'timestamp'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/datetime-vs-timestamp)
...Timestamps in MySQL generally used to track changes to records, and are updated every time the record is changed. If you want to store a specific value you should use a datetime field.

Change your MySQL schema to something closer to:

...

- phone VARCHAR(12)  NULL,
- date DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE NULL,
- time TIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIME NULL,

...

Comment: :) I m trying each and everything not working lol, You can also check You ans in your prompt. Thanks