# How to convert w3c date to a custom format?

Tags: php, w3c

How do I to convert a w3c date to a custom format inside PHP?

My w3c date: "2015-02-26T03:11:41.000-03:00"
My custom format: "dd/mm/YYYY hh:mm:ss"

Has someone Any idea?

Comment: Refer : http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php   #Example-4

Comment: please google it before come over here. This is an simple question.

Comment: Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28243214/3567787

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
$dateTime = new DateTime('2015-02-26T03:11:41.000-03:00');
echo $dateTime->format('d/m/Y h:i:s');
```

By using the codes above, it will output:

```
26/02/2015 03:11:41
```

It's always suggested to use `DateTime` class whenever available, which will have Exception to handle unable parsing cases.

Comment: and how do you do the oppesite?. Convert date of 26/02/2015 03:11:41 to W3C format?

Comment: @Kosem Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45131564/convert-date-to-w3c-format)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for `date()`

```
// prints something like: Wednesday the 15th
echo date('l \t\h\e jS');
```

Check out the section about the parameters on the Docs link.

Comment: It is safer to use an instance DateTime() as it will allow you to using typehinting for all methods that manipulate dates, it makes modifying dates easier and more accurate and finally it allows you to change the timezone.

Comment: I wouldn't say safer, I would say more useful, just tried to made it simple as possible, will update my answer with that option.

Comment: You are right, Safer might have been the wrong word. I think less margin for human error might have been a better way to have got my point across :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$dateTime = new DateTime($dateVar);
$formatted = $dateTime->format("dd/mm/YYYY hh:mm:ss");
```

Comment: `dd/mm/YYYY hh:mm:ss` this is not a valid format in PHP

Comment: He/she is asking for "dd/mm/YYYY hh:mm:ss" format, and it's a valid format in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
DateTime::createFromFormat(DateTime::W3C,  $your_w3c_date_here)->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');
```