# Convert date to W3C format

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have date format (`YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.u`):

```
2017-05-05T18:20:26.000Z
```

I need to convert it, so it will be without ms (`.u`) and to add GMT zone at the end of it (`YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss+TZD`):

```
2017-05-05T18:20:26+00:00
```

How to do that? Should I use `format()` or `date_format()`?

Thank You!

Comment: Or maybe should I remove the .000Z using str_replace() and add +00:00 to the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `DateTime::createFromFormat()`.

```
$datestring = "2017-05-05T18:20:26.000Z";
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.u", $datestring);
```

Then use `format()` on `$date` as you need it.

- [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)
- [`DateTime::format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

Comment: That is it! Got it working. Thank You! :)