# datetime for mysql and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a task to read datetime from csv file by PHP and store them in mysql database. There are two format of datetime in csv file, the first is `DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss AM/PM`, the second is `MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm:ss AM/PM`. Then later, I need to select some rows for their datetime is in some period.

It seems a little confused. There are some questions in my brain:

1. It is easy to set varchar type in mysql table to store them. But it
   is dificult to select some rows later, since I need to convert
   string to datetime first and check if data between in a special
   period.
2. Another solution is to convert these datetime from string to
   datetime by PHP before storing in database. Then it is easy to
   select data later. But the first step is also a little complex.

I do not know if some one has any good ideas about this question, or some experience in similar problems.

Comment: you can store it as a timestamp. Use `strtotime()` and put it in your database as an int(10).

Comment: Make sure you read [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/datetime-vs-timestamp) before deciding whether you want to use `datetime` or an `int`.

Comment: store dates as date types. end of story.

Comment: you're serious? you've got to parse a file with dates in *both* mm-dd-yyyy and `dd/mm/yyyy` formats in the same file? What kind of insanity is that? The people who are giving you that file need to be locked away somewhere if they're expecting you to produce a reliable outcome from that.

Comment: I need to parse data from files to database. but to date, in some document are mm-dd-yyyy, others are dd/mm/yyyy. It's true. They should be string when they read from files.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly: never *ever* **EVER** store dates or date times in a database as strings.

NEVER.

Got that?

You should always convert them to the database's built-in `date` or `datetime` data types.

Failure to do this will bite you very very hard later on. For example, imagine trying to get the database to sort them in date order if they're saved as strings, especially if they're in varying formats. And if there's one thing that you can be sure of, when you've got a date in a database, you're going to need to query it based on entries on, after or before a given date. If you weren't going to need to do that sort of thing with them, there wouldn't be much point storing the date in the first place, so even if you haven't been asked to do it yet, consider it a given that it'll be asked for later. Therefore, always *always* ALWAYS store them in the correct data type and not as a varchar.

Next, the mixture of formats you've been asked to deal with.

This is insanity.

I loathe and detest PHP's [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function. It is slow, has some unfortunate quirks, and should generally be considered a legacy of the past and not used. However, in this case, it may just come to your rescue.

`strtotime()` is designed to accept a date string in an unknown format, parse it, and output the correct timestamp. Obviously, it has to deal with the existence of both `dd-mm-yyyy` and `mm-dd-yyyy` formats. It does this by guessing which of the two you meant by looking at the separator character.

If the date string uses slashes as the separator, then it assumes the format is `mm/dd/yyyy`. If it uses dashes, then it assumes `dd-mm-yyyy`. This is one of those little quirks that makes using `strtotime()` such a pain in normal usage. But here it is your friend.

The way it works is actually the direct opposite of the formats you've specified in the question. But it should be enough to help you. If you switch the slashes and dashes in your input strings, and pass the result to `strtotime()` it should produce the correct timestamps in all cases, according to the way you've described it in the question.

It should then be simple enough to save them correctly in the database.

However I would strongly recommend testing this very very thoroughly. And not being surprised if it breaks somewhere along the line. If you're being fed data in inconsistent formats, then there really isn't any way to guarantee that it'll be consistently inconsistent. Your program basically needs to just do the best it can with bad data.

You also need to raise some serious questions about the quality of the input data. No program can be expected to work reliably in this situation. Make it clear to whoever is supplying it that it isn't good enough. If the program breaks because of bad data, it's their fault, not yours.

Comment: Thanks you guys all. The program is not difficult if the input data is united. Because of bad data, I have to spend much more time to solve the problem.

Comment: @PhilipSong - so did my suggestion about `strtotime()` help then?