# Sort sql output by date what row

Tags: php, sql, date

What would be the best way to store date and time in sql databases?
Should i use date() or is there some other better way to do it? and if i should be able to sort by the dates, what kind of sql row should it be set to? a timestamp or datetime?

Comment: Check out this somewhat related post, regarding DATETIME vs TIMESTAMP

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/datetime-vs-timestamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both, the `DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP` can be sorted in their default formats. Using one of these two is the best way to follow instead of storing them as VARCHAR or other data-types.

I personally prefer using `DATETIME` over `TIMESTAMP` because of the limitation applied to it.