# Convert MySQL datetime to timestamp

Tags: mysql, datetime, timestamp

I am trying to convert datetime into timestamp but mysql is giving me warnings and also converted values are wrong. Here is SQL query

```
UPDATE table1 A, table2 B SET B.date_added=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(A.date_added, '%M %d %Y %h:%i%p')) WHERE A.id=B.id;
```

**Warnings**

```
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                                  |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1411 | Incorrect datetime value: '2011-06-11 20:29:02' for function str_to_date |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Result**

```
+---------------------+---------------------+
| date_added          | date_added          |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2012-02-23 06:12:45 | 2012-12-23 19:08:33 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

I also tried following query but it shows 0000-00-00 00:00:00 in timestamp field.

```
UPDATE table1 A, table2 B SET B.date_added=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(A.date_added) WHERE A.id=B.id;
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this please:

```
UPDATE table1 A, table2 B 
SET B.date_added = FROM_UNIXTIME(A.date_added) 
WHERE A.id=B.id
```

[Reference](http://www.epochconverter.com/programming/mysql-from-unixtime.php).
It seems like you have an issue with the way you format date stammp.
Also please look into this post: [Should I use field 'datetime' or 'timestamp'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/datetime-vs-timestamp)

Comment: I tried that as well, but why there is time diff table A `2012-02-23 06:12:45` table B `2012-12-23 21:01:57`

Comment: There is some weird stuff with time zones and FROM_UNIXTIME, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/17128732/20774 for an explanation

Answer (score 42):

`UPDATE table1 A, table2 B SET B.date_added=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(A.date_added) WHERE A.id=B.id;`

`UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-01-15 12:00:00');`
is sufficient to convert a mysql datetime to a Timestamp.

Answer (score 7):

On MySQL 5.5 this works fine:

```sql
UPDATE `some_table`
SET `timestamp_col` = `datetime_col`
```

with `datetime_col` of [type `DATETIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html) and `timestamp_col` of [type `TIMESTAMP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html).

That is: no needs of explicit type conversion.

Comment: oddly, sometimes this gives an error. Might be timezone dependent.

Comment: Set timezone to UTC and this runs without error, otherwise you may have datetimes that don't convert to a timestamp in the current time zone.

Answer (score 2):

You're using `'%M %d %Y %h:%i%p'` as the date format, but the warning shows a date string '2011-06-11 20:29:02', which doesn't match that format.  I.e., the year is first, and the time is in 24-hour format.

You could use `'%Y-%M-%d %T'` instead, that format would match the data.

See more on the date format codes here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format