# Why does the Django time zone setting effect epoch time?

Tags: mysql, django, timezone, epoch

I have a small Django project that imports data dumps from MongoDB into MySQL. Inside these Mongo dumps are dates stored in epoch time. I would expect epoch time to be the same regardless of time zone but what I am seeing is that the Django [TIME_ZONE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-TIME_ZONE) setting has an effect on the data created in MySQL.

I have been testing my database output with the MySQL [UNIX_TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) function. If I insert a date with the epoch of `1371131402880` (this includes milliseconds) I have my timezone set to `'America/New_York'`, UNIX_TIMESTAMP gives me `1371131402`, which is the same epoch time excluding milliseconds. However if I set my timezone to `'America/Chicago'` I get `1371127802`.

This is my code to convert the epoch times into Python `datetime` objects,

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.utils.timezone import utc

secs = float(epochtime) / 1000.0
dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(secs)
```

I tried to fix the issue by putting an explict timezone on the `datetime` object,

```
# epoch time is in UTC by default
dt = dt.replace(tzinfo=utc)
```

[PythonFiddle for the code](http://pythonfiddle.com/tests-for-epoch-issue)

I've tested this Python code in isolation and it gives me the expected results. However it does not give the correct results after inserting these object into MySQL through a Django model [DateTimeField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield) field.

Here is my MySQL query,

```
SELECT id, `date`, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`date`) FROM table
```

I test this by comparing the unix timestamp column in the result of this query against the MongoDB JSON dumps to see if the epoch matches.

What exactly is going on here? Why should timezone have any effect on epoch times?

Just for reference, I am using Django 1.5.1 and MySQL-python 1.2.4. I also have the Django [USE_TZ](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/) flag set to `true`.

Comment: Probably the MySQL server's timezone doesn't match your application's time zone. The problem is that MySQL interprets the argument to `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` as a local time in its own private time zone.

Comment: For best results, always set `SET TIME_ZONE="+00:00"` on all MySQL connections, and interpret every date as UTC.

Comment: Terminology - an "epoch" is just the reference date that we set the zero at.  Most of the time it is 1/1/1970 UTC, but that doesn't mean integers based on this date should be called "epoch time".  There are plenty of other epoch dates used in other systems.

Comment: @Celada - that doesn't seem right to me, but I'm not a MySQL expert.  Can you back it up with some reference link?  If so, please put in an answer.  Everything I know about dates in this format says that UTC is always the reference time zone.  It seems more likely that somewhere it is changing types or calling a function that introduces the local time zone.

Comment: @MattJohnson: Celada is right, this is a "best practice". Always store in UTC and convert to the user TZ at display time.

Comment: @PauloScardine - Of course, I understand that.  That's not what I was debating.  I am saying that I don't think MySQL would take a unix timestamp integer and treat it as local time.  If it does, that's fairly bizarre IMHO.  I know of no other system, platform or language that actually alters the timestamp because of timezone settings.

Comment: Ok, I just read through [these mysql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) and now I understand.  Celada did say "the argument" to that function, which is a string containing a formatted datetime value.  Yes - it makes sense that it would apply it's `TIME_ZONE` setting to this value.  My point was that the underlying integer is then converted to UTC.  So when represented as an integer, UTC is always the reference point regardless of the local time zone.  I just got caught up in the wording. Appologies.

Comment: Just for reference, both MySQL server I've run this on are set to `-04:00:00` which is EDT, my local timezone. I still don't understand why that would effect a unix epoch time.

Comment: What mysql data type is the `date` column?  and can you show an example of a value that it might contain?

Comment: @MattJohnson, it is a standard MySQL DATETIME column. Nothing fancy there.

Comment: Ok, I was just checking if it was `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`.  They behave differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no python or Django guru, so perhaps someone can answer better than me.  But I will take a guess at it anyway.

You said that you were storing it in a Django `DateTimeField`, which according to [the documents you referenced](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield), stores it as a Python `datetime`.

Looking at [the docs for `datetime`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/datetime.html), I think the key is understanding the difference between "naive" and "aware" values.

And then researching further, I came across [this excellent reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/).  Be sure the read the second section, "Naive and aware datetime objects".  That gives a bit of context to how much of this is being controlled by Django.  Basically, by setting `USE_TZ = true`, you are asking Django to use *aware* datetimes instead of *naive* ones.

So then I looked back at you question.  You said you were doing the following:

```
dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(secs)
dt = dt.replace(tzinfo=utc)
```

Looking at the [fromtimestamp](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp) function documentation, I found this bit of text:

> If optional argument `tz` is `None` or not specified, the `timestamp` is converted to the platform’s local date and time, and the returned `datetime` object is naive.

So I think you could do this:

```
dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(secs, tz=utc)
```

Then again, right below that function, the docs show `utcfromtimestamp` function, so maybe it should be:

```
dt = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(secs)
```

I don't know enough about python to know if these are equivalent or not, but you could try and see if either makes a difference.

Hopefully one of these will make a difference. If not, please let me know.  I'm intimately familiar with date/time in JavaScript and in .Net, but I'm always interested in how these nuances play out differently in other platforms, such as Python.

### Update

Regarding the MySQL portion of the question, take a look at [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bbcfa/1).

```
CREATE TABLE foo (`date` DATETIME);
INSERT INTO foo (`date`) VALUES (FROM_UNIXTIME(1371131402));

SET TIME_ZONE="+00:00";
select `date`, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`date`) from foo;

SET TIME_ZONE="+01:00";
select `date`, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`date`) from foo;
```

Results:

```
DATE                           UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`DATE`)
June, 13 2013 13:50:02+0000    1371131402
June, 13 2013 13:50:02+0000    1371127802
```

It would seem that the behavior of `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` function is indeed affected by the MySQL `TIME_ZONE` setting.  That's not so surprising, since it's in the documentation.  What's surprising is that the string output of the `datetime` has the same UTC value regardless of the setting.

Here's what I think is happening.  In the docs for the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` function, it says:

> `date` may be a `DATE` string, a `DATETIME` string, a `TIMESTAMP`, or a number in the format `YYMMDD` or `YYYYMMDD`.

Note that it doesn't say that it can be a `DATETIME` - it says it can be a `DATETIME` ***string***.  So I think the actual value being implicitly converted to a string before being passed into the function.

So now look at [this updated fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bbcfa/2) that converts explicitly.

```
SET TIME_ZONE="+00:00";
select `date`, convert(`date`, char), UNIX_TIMESTAMP(convert(`date`, char)) from foo;

SET TIME_ZONE="+01:00";
select `date`, convert(`date`, char), UNIX_TIMESTAMP(convert(`date`, char)) from foo;
```

Results:

```
DATE                           CONVERT(`DATE`, CHAR)  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONVERT(`DATE`, CHAR))
June, 13 2013 13:50:02+0000    2013-06-13 13:50:02    1371131402
June, 13 2013 13:50:02+0000    2013-06-13 13:50:02    1371127802
```

You can see that when it converts to character data, it strips away the offset.  So of course, it makes sense now that when `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` takes this value as input, it is assuming the local time zone setting and thus getting a different UTC timestamp.

Not sure if this will help you or not.  You need to dig more into exactly how Django is calling MySQL for both the read and the write.  Does it actually use the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` function? Or was that just what you did in testing?

Comment: `utcfromtimestamp()` is the correct function to create a naive datetime object that represents time in UTC. Mere `fromtimestamp()` would return a naive datetime in local timezone (wrong thing in most cases unless you want to display it on the local system immediately).

Comment: Thanks for taking a stab at it Matt. I was actually playing with `utcfromtimestamp` earlier, but didn't have much luck with it. It was inserting UTC times into the database and the unix timestamps were even further off. I try to post up some more info later. Also I will have to give your recommendation of `secs, tz=utc` a try, at the very least that will save me a line of code :)

Comment: Yes, please show the code you were testing with the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` function. That code is probably affected by timezone as Celada described.

Comment: UNIX_TIMESTAMP is a MySQL function, but I'll add the query. Also I added a PythonFiddle @ http://pythonfiddle.com/tests-for-epoch-issue

Comment: Ugh I missed that part about the string conversion, that is really unintuitive. Good write up of how this actually works, it's possible that my confirmation tests were flawed.

Comment: The more I read those over the less sense it makes, why does MySQL's `select date` column show the same date for different timezones, that makes no sense to me.

Comment: That's the behavior of `DATETIME`.  If you want it to adjust, use `TIMESTAMP`.  See [this updated fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab8b2/1) and note that the dates are now adjusted, but the unix timestamps are in sync.  See also [these docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/time-zone-support.html)

Comment: Just for the record my confirmation tests were flawed among this issue being really complex. Sorry if this isn't the greatest Q&A fit, this issue just spiraled out of control.