# MySQL select timestamp col as seconds

Tags: php, mysql, date, pdo

I wanna select a timestamp column that contain a date.

I want the result in **seconds**, I've tryed this but **it's not working**.

```
$req = $database->query('SELECT energy, maxEnergy, DATE_FORMAT(last_attack, "%s") FROM users WHERE id = '.$userID.'');
```

**last_attack column contain :** 2018-09-05 09:26:38

And the result give me : `["DATE_FORMAT(last_attack, "%s")"]=> string(2) "38"`

I don't want the seconds in my date, I want all the date converted in seconds...

What am I doing wrong ? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert MySQL datetime to timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014641/convert-mysql-datetime-to-timestamp)

Comment: _I want the result in seconds_... seconds relative to what? UNIX epoch? Current time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me you are looking for the amount of `seconds` passed since the `last_attack`. You should use [`TIMESTAMPDIFF()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) to achieve that.

```
select TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, '2018-09-05 09:26:38', NOW());
```

`TIMESTAMPDIFF()` accepts three parameters `unit`, `date_time1` and `date_time2` and returns the difference between `date_time2` and `date_time1` (`date_time2 - date_time`) in `unit`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`

Select `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(last_attack)` as `my_required` from users...

Answer (score 0):

use TIME_TO_SEC

```
SELECT energy, maxEnergy, TIME_TO_SEC(last_attack) FROM users WHERE id = '.$userID.'
```