# Timestamp in MySQL not updating despite updating records

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a column which contains a timestamp in my MySQL database. No matter how many times I update my records, my timestamps are not updated. Is there anything I should do to make it auto update?

Searching other questions here in Stackoverflow, most of them say the opposite, it's really very confusing! For example, this one,  [Should I use field 'datetime' or 'timestamp'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/datetime-vs-timestamp) (Look at the top rated answer)

Thank you

Here is my table structure

```
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field          | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Num            | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| mem_name       | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| mem_id         | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| car_number     | varchar(11) | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| firstcall_time | timestamp   | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| tow_time       | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

One Record:

+-----+----------+--------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| Num | mem_name | mem_id | car_number | firstcall_time      | tow_time            |
+-----+----------+--------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|   1 | Jakey    |  54564 | SHA34345   | 2013-02-19 16:14:12 | 2013-02-19 16:32:45 |
+-----+----------+--------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

After Updating:

+-----+----------+--------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| Num | mem_name | mem_id | car_number | firstcall_time      | tow_time            |
+-----+----------+--------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|   1 | Tommy    |  54564 | SHA34345   | 2013-02-19 16:14:12 | 2013-02-19 16:32:45 |
+-----+----------+--------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Does this field has `ON UPDATE...` clause defined? Can you show the results of `SHOW TABLE...` for the table you speak about?

Comment: Is the update value set to on_update_current_timestamp?

Comment: I created the table from phpmyadmin by choosing the fields in the drop down menu, I'm pretty new to SQL. Sorry, can you give me the full command? I tried "SHOW TABLE tbl_name", it gives an error.

Comment: Do you have multiple timestamp columns. Can you post your table structure here.

Comment: Just posted my table structure

Comment: Guys, any ideas? I posted an updated entry of the table too! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main reason that your timestamp  is not updating beacuse you have not added `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` clause in your table creation statement.

Change it with alter table command and modify your column

```
With both DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
the column has the current timestamp for its default value and 
is automatically updated to the current timestamp.
```

You must add On UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  id int, ts2 TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
            ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Edit - Table modifying command

```
alter table <tablename> modify <columnName> TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
        ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Refer http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Comment: I see, I created my table in phpmyadmin, is there a way to add the ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP through the Phpmyadmin interface without manually typing the ALTER table command?

Answer (score 5):

Add `On UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

MySQL Query:

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` CHANGE `date_field` `date_field` TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Hope it helps !