# Django usage of DATETIME in SQL table django_admin_log

Tags: django, datetime, django-admin, timestamp

Why doesn't Django in SQL table django_admin_log use TIMESTAMP instead of DATETIME for attribute action_time? I mean according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/409305/535661) it should be using TIMESTAMP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LogEntry's `action_time` field is a [`models.DateTimeField`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/models.py#L25), which (perhaps unsurprisingly) is [stored as a `DATETIME` field](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/backends/mysql/creation.py#L16).

I think you've misunderstood [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/datetime-vs-timestamp/409305#409305) you linked - it recommends using `DATETIME`, not `TIMESTAMP`:

> If you meant that you want to decide between using a UNIX timestamp or a native MySQL datetime field, go with the native format. You can do calculations within MySQL that way (`"SELECT DATE_ADD(my_datetime, INTERVAL 1 DAY)"`) and it is simple to change the format of the value to a UNIX timestamp (`"SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(my_datetime)"`) when you query the record if you want to operate on it with PHP.

Comment: Yeah that is true. But the first part of that answer clearly says this: `Timestamps in MySQL generally used to track changes to records, and are often updated every time the record is changed`

Comment: I think the first word "Timestamp" there is referring to the concept of a time value, not the MySQL field type (note that it's not capitalised).