# Mysql time records as Unixtime instead of Mysql Timestamp

Tags: mysql, time, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I have a table with 10000 records . Each data have a time of creation. I can use PHP time() function or as Mysql Timestamp (DATETIME '0000-00-00 00:00:00').
I want to know which method increase the performance of select queries? 
For example

```
Select * FROM MYDB WHERE datefield>1343821692 ORDER BY datefield DESC
```

or

```
Select * FROM MYDB WHERE datefield>'2012-08-01 13:41:1' ORDER BY datefield DESC
```

Please note that question bases on differences of INT sorting instead of DATETIME order. Also differences on restrictions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [datetime vs timestamp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/datetime-vs-timestamp)

Comment: It is similar but not duplicated. Here I am interesting for performance WHEN I AM USING DATES AS "ORDER BY" AND RESTRICTION.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know which method increase the performance of select
>   queries?

If one setup was bound to disk usage, one would expect INT to perform better, since storage requirements are smaller. However, the amount of calculations to use it as a timestamp can be overwhelming as well.

Check [this](http://gpshumano.blogs.dri.pt/2009/07/06/mysql-datetime-vs-timestamp-vs-int-performance-and-benchmarking-with-myisam/) out.

As far as there usage is concerned you can refer this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/datetime-vs-timestamp) which will guide you when to use unix_time and when to use the other

Comment: Sorting INT is faster than sorting DATETIME or reverse?

Comment: @Huseyin:- Yes you are right. Int is comparatively faster. I have updated my answer with a link which shows the difference. Hope it helps!!! And sorry for the previous answer :)