# Update mysql table column

Tags: mysql, sql

In mysql database I've **contact_details** table. In this table a column name **created_date2** contain following date values :

```
Formate : m / d y 
-----------------
10/10/2014 
10/10/2014 
6/19/2013 
6/19/2013
6/19/2013
6/19/2013
6/19/2013
6/19/2013
6/19/2013
6/19/2013
10/10/2014
10/10/2014 
10/10/2014 
3/10/2014
```

I want to update this column value which **Month (m)** has not **Zero (0)** to 06, 07 08 etc. For example, As you can see there are a few date **6/19/2013.** I wan tto update this to **06/19/2013** using `sql query`. Can someone tell how can I do this ?

Note : I can do this by manually but there are more than 2500 rows exist !!

Comment: which data type is used for date     if it is data format  then you can save y/m/d format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure, this is for the first part i.e. the month part problem only, then try this:

```
UPDATE contact_details 
SET created_date2 = CONCAT('0', created_date2) 
WHERE LENGTH(created_date2) < 10
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply But it's not updating.

Comment: Currently created_date2 column has char(20) data type. Can I change it to timestamp data type ? If so then will it be 0000000000 ? (I want to change the current date value to timestamp format)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18842892/what-happens-when-changing-column-type-timestamp-to-datetime-in-mysql

Comment: and to change the existing data to timestamp you need to update it first:
`UPDATE contact_details SET created_date2=FROM_UNIXTIME(created_date2) 
`

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE mytable 
   SET col = IFNULL(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE( col ,'%m/%d/%Y'),'%m/%d/%Y'), col )
```

Comment: Currently `created_date2` column has char(20) data type. Can I change it to `timestamp` data type ? If so then will it be `0000000000` ? (I want to change the current `date value` to `timestamp` format)