# timestamp format in mysql and perl

Tags: mysql, perl

I am not familiar with timestamp format much.

I have a text for example

```
'Jul 19, 2013 12:00 pm'
```

I want to store it to mysql. What format of this timestamp is in MySQL and how should I format it properly in perl before passing it to mysql.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### What is the format of timestamps in MySQL?

I *highly* recommend that you read the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index.html). You'll get your answers much faster than by posting a question on StackOverflow. From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html):

> TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.

As you can see, the format is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`.

As [ysth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17389/ysth) points out in the comments, MySQL also has a `DATETIME` data type:

> MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.

Several things to note:

- `DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP` both use the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`
- The range of dates supported by `DATETIME` is *much* larger than the range for `TIMESTAMP`
- `TIMESTAMP` converts values to UTC for storage and back to the local time zone on retrieval; `DATETIME` does no time zone conversion

If you aren't already wedded to the `TIMESTAMP` data type you might consider using `DATETIME` instead, depending on what kind of data you're trying to store. See [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/datetime-vs-timestamp) for more details on `DATETIME` vs. `TIMESTAMP`.

### How should I format it in Perl before passing it to MySQL?

To convert date/time strings to different formats in Perl, you can use the core (since v5.9) module [Time::Piece](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html#Date-Parsing):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Time::Piece;

my $date = 'Jul 19, 2013 12:00 pm';
my $t = Time::Piece->strptime($date, '%b %d, %Y %I:%M %p');
say $t->strftime('%F %T');
# 2013-07-19 12:00:00
```

It's not clear from your example date string whether the day and hour are zero-padded. The above example assumes a format like

> Oct **01**, 2013 **05**:00 am

where days and hours less than ten begin with a zero. If your input format is actually

> Oct **1**, 2013 **5**:00 am

then you need to change the format string passed to `Time::Piece->strptime`. A list of format specifiers can be found in the [man page for strftime](http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/3/strftime/).

Comment: mysql also has a datetime type; often that is a better choice.

Comment: @ysth The OP asked about "timestamp" so I just assumed that they already have a column using the `TIMESTAMP` data type. Probably shouldn't have jumped to conclusions; I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Time::Piece](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html) has been a Perl core module since 5.9.  It provides a convenient way to parse any time format input (with `strptime()`) and produce a differently formatted output (with `strftime()`.

```
#cat ./tconv
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;
my $t = Time::Piece->strptime( shift, "%b %d, %Y %I:%M %p" );
print $t->epoch, "\n";
print $t->strftime( $t, "%Y/%m/%d %T %z" ), "\n";

#./tconv "Jul 19, 2013 12:00 pm"
1374235200
Fri Jul 19 12:00:00 2013
```

Comment: And there's always `strftime` from the [`POSIX`](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.8/POSIX.html) module.