# What should i use to save date and time

Tags: php, sql

For my new database i want to save a given date and time and year from php to my database with mysqli, in sql i can make a field :

```
DATE

DATETIME

TIMESTAMP

TIME

YEAR
```

I'm using the database only with php, what type should i select? and for what reason.

I think datetime and timestamp are the best options. but cant find any reason why 1 should be better then the other. Can someone help me to chose ?

Or is it better to save date time and year separate?

I want to make querys to get values from last week etc.

Comment: Depends on what you're going to use. If you're storing a date, don't use a `TIMESTAMP`. If you're storing a timestamp, don't use a `DATE`. If you don't need time, don't use `DATETIME`.

Comment: I personally use datetime for user specified / variable dates and timestamp with store current on insert enable when I just need to store the now() time on record insert.  They're all much of a muchness though I just personally find datetime/timestamps easier to deal with

Comment: i want to store the date time and year of an event .

Comment: the first timestamp field in a table will auto-update anytime you modify the record. maybe that's what you want, but if you're storing (say) HR records, you don't want someone's birthday to always be "now".

Comment: See that discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/datetime-vs-timestamp

Comment: I want to store something like a birthday so not the current date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For my new database i want to save a given date and time and year from php to my database

So, store it as `DATETIME`. It includes the year.

Here is how look at those types:

- `DATE`: use for dates (with years), for example a a birthdate ("2010-11-23")
- `TIME`: use for a time in a day, for example the start of your lunch ("12:00")
- `DATETIME`: use for a specific date and time, for example the start of a meeting ("2010-11-23 12:00")
- `TIMESTAMP`:    use for when a specific thing happened, for example the time a certain meeting was created ("1385653500"; this often includes timezone information in its definition)
- `YEAR`: use to store a year, for example the start year of a war ("1653")

Note that you can always cast "larger" types to "smaller" types. E.g. you can cast a `DATE` into a `YEAR`.

Comment: timestamp includes years to right?

Comment: @SvenB yes, it can be calculated from its definition (many timestamps exist out there), I added some examples for each in my answer.

Comment: Just a note `TIMESTAMP` can also store date im datetime format ie `yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:ss` it doesn't HAVE to store it as an epoch time stamp