# Datetime and Timestamp in Mysql Database Table

Tags: mysql

Which is the better choice to choose whether timestamp or datetime.. I'm currently  working in mysql . for date and time field in database table which is the better one??
and the reason to choose it??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/datetime-vs-timestamp?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

**Timestamp** is used when you need modified date or insert date which automatically inserted by the system at the time of insert or edit record.

And **datetime** is use for you have to insert it when you are insert or edit record.

Choice is you to you What you required.

Thanks