# Is timestamp in mysql cached when retrieved in different timezones?

Tags: mysql, performance, caching, timezone, timestamp

In the MySQL 5.6 Manual, it says:

> MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval.

but if I have different connections with different timezones, will the timestamp value be cached?

Answer (score 1):

According to OZ_ [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/datetime-vs-timestamp#comment6682760_409305):

> Another one difference: queries with "native" datetime will not be cached, but queries with timestamp - will be. –  OZ_ Apr 28 '11 at 17:37

But I cannot find any confirmation of this by Googling, and he doesn't provide a link.