# mysql time application that will expire in 30 days

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create an application that will expire in 30 days from the time of the product entry into database.

1: I know of timestamp and datetime. which of them do i used.
2: how do i minus the present time from the 30 days of the product expiration and then insert it to database.

Comment: For the first question, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/datetime-vs-timestamp. For the second, use `DATE_SUB()`.

Comment: I have put up an answer because i think i know what you are trying to do, but please put up some code of things you have tried.

Comment: my product has a closing date in 30 days. my question is how do i convert 30 days into time and then insert into mysql database via insert statements or php

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your date column is `my_date` like

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
    `my_date` DATETIME
)
```

You can do something like the following to add timestamp 30 days in the future:

```
INSERT INTO `my_table` SET `my_date` = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY);
```