# CakePHP inserting timestamp, how to?

Tags: cakephp, timestamp

I would like to save timestamp value into column.

If i trying to do by this way:

```
$SessionData['valid_till'] = time() + WEEK;
```

I get right number value. But into column is already saved value like this:

```
0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

How can i do it right way in CakePHP?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Make sure you use date() or DateTime object and the type of your db field is "datetime".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 $SessionData['valid_till'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+1 week"));
```

Comment: Is not better to use datetime in this case? I thought that i can save integer values, not formatted date.

Comment: At least with MySQL, though the datatype timestamp seems to be implemented behind the scenes as a unix timestamp, you deal with the data as a formatted string, the same as datetime.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html  As for when timestamp should be used, people generally say for "created" and "updated" only -- See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/datetime-vs-timestamp