# how to use insert query at actual code programing

Tags: sql, vb.net

Im running this query at my SQL and it is good.

```
INSERT INTO db.tbl (col1, col2, col3) values ('1.68','2014/01/01 05:00:00', Date_add(col2, interval col1 day_second));
```

My code is not working but the computation at last column is wrong

```
cmd = New Odbc.OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO room.save(exacttime, depletion_time, time_inputed) values ('" & lblexact.Text & "','" & Trim(TextBox6.Text) & "',' Date_add( exacttime, interval depletion_time day_second)')", con)           
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: it still eror exception

Comment: Why is there a random `'` at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PS: I am not familiar with vb.net, so not sure if this is the right way to do (*So, no downvotes pls!!*),.  But as per sql, there are some unwanted single quotes that needs to be removed.

```
cmd = New Odbc.OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO room.save(exacttime, depletion_time, time_inputed) values ('" & lblexact.Text & "','" & Trim(TextBox6.Text) & "',
Date_add( exacttime, interval depletion_time day_second))", con)   
^                                                        ^
|-----------------Single Quotes Removed------------------|
```

Comment: do i need to use time stamp again?\

Comment: Youre correct but one last question, could you give 1 more column for every result minus 1 hour. thanks

Comment: Seriously I have no idea of .net. Since I found extra single quotes in sql query, I posted as answer.  So, I am unable to understand what is results minus 1 hour..

Comment: If this helped you solve your current problem, you can accept as answer. Probably you can ask as a separate question which .net experts would be able to help you with.

Comment: sir, can you help me again with my format insert I just add 1 column and 1 data and it is running in my SQL please last....  cmd = New Odbc.OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO room.save( exacttime, depletion_time, expected_dip_time, expected_dip_time2) values ('" & lblexact.Text & "','" & Trim(TextBox6.Text) & "',Date_add( exacttime, interval depletion_time day_second)) " & ",DATE_SUB(Date_add( exacttime, interval depletion_time day_second), interval 1 hour)", con)

Comment: Try this:  cmd = New Odbc.OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO room.save( exacttime, depletion_time, expected_dip_time, expected_dip_time2) values ('" & lblexact.Text & "','" & Trim(TextBox6.Text) & "',Date_add( exacttime, interval depletion_time day_second) ,DATE_SUB(Date_add( exacttime, interval depletion_time day_second), interval 1 hour)) ", con)

Answer (score 1):

**Always** use [parameterized/prepared SQL queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i). Here's how your code should look like.

```vb
Using con As New Odbc.OdbcConnection("...")
    Using cmd As New Odbc.OdbcCommand()

        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = <!--
            INSERT INTO db.tbl (
                col1, 
                col2, 
                col3
            ) VALUES (
                @p1,
                @p2,
                @p3
            );
        -->.Value

        Dim value1 As Double = Double.Parse(labeldatetime.Text)
        Dim value2 As Date = Date.Parse(textboxtime.Text)
        Dim value3 As Date = value2.AddSeconds(value1)

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", value1)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", value2)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", value3)

    End Using
End Using
```

Note that the you don't need a `XComment`, I just used it to make it more readable.

Comment: it still eror exception

Comment: @user3795723 `it still eror exception` tells us... well, **nothing**. You need to provide a full error description. Also, do as I say, use parameterized / prepared SQL queries.

Comment: yes already tried that but theres still error, im using timestamp at my database. You have an error in your SQL Sytax ODBC Exception

Comment: please see my real data in my rewrite question.

Comment: @user3795723 So `col1` is double, `col2` and `col3` are timestamps?

Comment: yup!, do i need to change? or what?

Comment: im not using col1,2,3. I rewrite to my real data = depletion_time, exacttime, timeinputed... depletion_time is varchar, exacttime and timeinputed are timestamp

Comment: @user3795723 You need to edit your question so that it includes the following: 1) The sql table schema. 2) The data type of your input fields. Names like `TextBox6` and `lblexact` doesn't reveal this.

Comment: depletion_time -> Double,. exacttime -> Timestamp,. timeinputed -> Timestamp,. room -> Schema,. save -> table,. I already rewrite my schema and data type. Take another look at my question, I already put my real data's.

Comment: @user3795723 You should change the data type of the columns to `DateTime`. You might want to see this SO link: [datetime vs timestamp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/datetime-vs-timestamp).

Comment: I already change the data type to datetime but still not inserting to my database

Comment: Do I need to rewrite my code? or what.

Comment: @user3795723 What's the error message?

Comment: My code is now working its all inserting but the problem is when I insert exacttime give me default value 000-00-00 00:00:00 not computing my depletion_time and time_inputed