# Insert string to timestamp fails

Tags: mysql

I have a table

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test (stamp TIMESTAMP);
```

And try to run inserts on it

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES('2003-01-01')
```

Fails with Incorrect datetime value: '2003-01-01' for column 'stamp' at row 1

And this one works

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES('2004-01-01')
```

Why would that happen?

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `TIMESTAMP`:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `test` (`stamp` DATETIME);
```

You need to give that in the right format:

```
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES ('2004-01-01 00:00:00')
```

Comment: That one works. But INSERT INTO `test` VALUES ('2003-01-01 0:00:00') still fails

Comment: @clorz Check this out!

Comment: `0:00:00` is not valid. it's `hh:mm:ss`, not `h:mm:ss`. the zero-padding counts.

Comment: INSERT INTO `test` VALUES ('2003-01-01 00:00:00') also fails

Comment: @clorz Did you try creating it as a `DATETIME`?

Comment: @clorz `TIMESTAMP` is related to `UPDATE` function.

Comment: @clorz Check this out: [datetime vs timestamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/datetime-vs-timestamp)

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I'll use datetime instead. But this still seem puzzling. As if that particular hour did not exist. Even INSERT INTO `test` VALUES ('2003-01-01 01:00:00') works, but anything below 01:00:00 does not.